# Efficient conditional Mean[] on a large data set

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization

Consider a list, `AK6`, that has 382 sublists of length varying from 2500 to 3000. Each "subsublist" is as such : `AK6[[1,1]]={5.5,1001}`

With `AK6[[All,1]]` going from 1001 to 4001 with gaps (missing points)

I now need to compute the `Mean[]` for all the sublists with equal second value. That is `Select` with `Flatten[AK6,1]` all the list with 2005 as the second value (from 350 to 384 items approx)

I do this using :

```
ParallelTable[
             Mean[Select[Flatten[AK6s, 1], #[[2]] == gazeNo &][[All,1]]], 
             {gazeNo, Range[1000, 4000, 1]}]
```

It does what I need but this is very slow. Is there a way to do this computation faster?

---

Download the 13 MB list as

```
AK6 = Uncompress@Import["http://api2.ge.tt/0/9F8d6WD/0/blob/download", "String"];
```

Comment: I compressed and re-uploaded the file---it was way too big at 35 MB.

Comment: @Szabolcs, how did you compress the file? Worth a new question ?

Comment: `Export["data.dat.gz", Compress[AK6], "String"]`.  `Compress` gives an ASCII (i.e. 7-bit) string, so I did an additional gzip compression in `Export` to shave off some 10-12%.  Ideally one could just `Export` to `WDX` (which I think is already compressed) but with this amount of data it is just too slow.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thank you, how do you then import the data in the correct format ?

Comment: You can use `data = Uncompress@Import["data.dat.gz", "String"];`.  `Import` and `Export` will automatically handle compressing to or uncompressing from `gz` if they detect that the file is gzip-compressed.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
mean = Reap[Sow @@@ Flatten[cogAK6, 1];, _, {Mean[#2], #} &][[2]];
```

This will be a lot faster than your approach because by using `Sow` and `Reap` this code only iterates through the list of data once. In your code, you reiterate through all elements of the data list for every value of `gazeNo` (so 3000 times instead of only once).

Comment: Thank You very much. I am in shock by how fast this was. Could you explain what makes this so fast?

Comment: By using `Sow` and `Reap` this code only iterates through the list of data once. In your code, you reiterate through all elements of the data list for every value of gazNo (so 3000 times instead of only once).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Just replacing `_` with `Range[1000,4000]` should do it I suppose (and probably checking for an empty list when applying `Mean`). I agree that it's a powerful technique, so I thank you just in case you are the one who introduced it to me.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  There is no need to check for empty lists as the function is not applied of nothing is Reaped.  You can also nest this construct to make it multidimensional.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard and that form is eerily similar to my [general one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4225830/198315).

Comment: @rcollyer indeed it is, and posted before I posted mine.  Nevertheless I don't believe I understood the similarity until well after.  I find that I learn best from simple, pithy bits of code, and this is probably why I also post (what I hope are) that kind of answers.  Take the "A and B n times" answers as an example; I answered in very simple terms, without the complication of `Module`, and at last check ten people found that valuable.  Again I think we each bring something to the table, even though I am incapable of regularly producing the kind of answers Leonid does.

Answer (score 20):

This answer will be about efficiency, no ambitions for the beauty contest participation here. Since you mentioned speed, and only need mean values, here is a method that will be an order of magnitude faster and order of magnitude more memory-efficient than the (fine) solutions offered so far.

#### Code

First, we make a compiled function generator:

```
ClearAll[generateFastMean];
generateFastMean[maxIndex_Integer?Positive] :=
   Compile[{{data, _Real, 2}},
     Module[{means = Table[0., {maxIndex}], num = Table[0, {maxIndex}], 
      ctr = 0, i = 0, index = 0, resultIndices =  Table[0, {maxIndex}],
      indexHash = Table[0, {maxIndex}]},
     Do[
       index = IntegerPart[data[[i, 2]]];
       means[[index]] += data[[i, 1]];
       num[[index]]++;
       If[indexHash[[index]] == 0,
          indexHash[[index]] = 1;
          resultIndices[[++ctr]] = index
       ];,
       {i, Length[data]}
     ];
     resultIndices = Take[resultIndices, ctr];
     Transpose[{resultIndices, means[[resultIndices]]/num[[resultIndices]]}]
    ], (* Module *)
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

What happens here is that I exploit the fact that your indices are not too large integers, and use arrays as hash-tables to keep the data I accumulate. At the end, I extract only those indices which are present, and compute means by dividing a list of totals by a list of index frequencies. Since your indices are smaller than 5000, I will generate the function accordingly:

```
fastMean = generateFastMean[5000];
```

#### The case at hand

First, we load the data (by the way, compressing is a fine idea but one can have additional savings, see below):

```
AK6 = Uncompress@Import["http://api2.ge.tt/0/9F8d6WD/0/blob/download", "String"];
```

To reduce the memory this occupies, we `Flatten` the list as:

```
AK6PFl1 =  Join @@Map[Developer`ToPackedArray, AK6]
```

Just to illustrate what kind of savings I am speaking about:

```
ByteCount /@ {AK6PFl, Flatten[AK6, 1]}

(*
  ==> {18238440, 127667944}
*)
```

So, we are looking at the order of magnitude here. Ok, now computing:

```
fastMean[AK6PFl1] //Short[#,5]&//AbsoluteTiming

(*
  ==> {0.063,{{1000.,5.00499},{1001.,5.00541},{1002.,5.00556},<<2995>>,
       {3998.,3.72284},{3999.,3.72058},{4000.,3.71838}}}
*)
```

#### How to store the data

While `Compress` is a good idea, I would supplement it with converting sublists to packed arrays, as illustrated above. So, you can do

```
Export["C:\\Temp\\AK6.dat", Compress@Map[Developer`ToPackedArray, AK6], "String"]
```

Then, the import is fast, *and* there is no unpacking (which happens with the current version of the file):

```
Uncompress@Import["C:\\Temp\\AK6.dat","String"]//ByteCount//AbsoluteTiming

(*
 ==> {0.594,18305896}
*)
```

The idea of combining `Compress` and packed arrays (in a somehwat more complex setting since I made the data self-uncompressing), allowed me to get the remarkable performance in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247005/efficiently-working-with-and-generating-large-text-files/8250860#8250860), and seems to represent a general method.

#### Remarks

I cheated because I did not include the compilation time, which is significant. However, if you have to do this many times, this may pay off. Of course, this will all make sense only when you need extreme performance, but I think it is good to understand what your performance limitations really are, for a given problem (I do not claim that the code has been fully optimized).

Comment: When you want to time especially c-compiled stuff, you should always use `AbsoluteTiming`, everything else is not what you want.

Comment: @halirutan That's a good point, but in my experience, this is more relevant for running external programs (e.g. Mathlink). C-compiled function becomes a part of the kernel process, so there should be no real difference between using `Timing` on it and some  built-in function. In particular, I re-checked with `AbsoluteTiming` and got the same results. But I agree with you in general, and will edit accordingly.

Comment: You have to be careful when using the parallelization in compiled functions, because it can happen that the cpu-times of each processors are added up. Let me try an example code: `f = Compile[{{i, _Integer}}, i^2, CompilationTarget -> "C", 
  Parallelization -> True, 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]; With[{arg = 
   RandomInteger[{0, 100}, 10^7]}, 
 First[#[f[arg]]] & /@ {Timing, AbsoluteTiming}]`

Comment: @halirutan Yes, I agree - for this case, probably because of threading. I do know about this, and had I used parallel, I would have used `AbsoluteTiming` from the start.

Answer (score 14):

Heike already got Sow/Reap so here is GatherBy:

```
<< cogAK6.m;
j = Join @@ cogAK6;
j[[All, 2]] = Round@j[[All, 2]];

{#[[1, 2]], Mean[#[[All, 1]]]} & /@ GatherBy[j, Last] // Sort
```

Both methods are fast because you do not repeatedly rescan the data for each `gazeNo`.

By the way I added Round just to be sure that values were properly gathered in case there were slight variations.

Comment: Wizard, thank you for your attention !

Answer (score 9):

Here is another compiled effort (this will be ugly):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Compile[
   {
    {vals, _Real, 1},
    {ind, _Integer, 1}
    },
   Module[
    {
     s = ConstantArray[0., 4000],
     n = ConstantArray[0, 4000]
     },
    Do[
     s[[ind[[i]]]] += vals[[i]];
     n[[ind[[i]]]]++,
     {i, 1, Length@ind}
     ];
    Transpose[{Drop[s, 999]/N@Drop[n, 999], Range[1000, 4000]}]
    ],
   CompilationTarget \[Rule] "C"
   ];
```

then

```
({vals, ind} = Transpose@Flatten[AK6, 1];
  mean2 = f[vals, ind];) // AbsoluteTiming
```

takes 0.223913s.

EDIT: comparing to Leonid's code (which looks less ugly than this to me), this is a tiny bit faster (Leonid's code here takes 0.26s if I include the `generateFastMean[5000]` part (or maybe not--I should run it many times and compare).

Comment: Actually, it is somewhat more economical than mine, since I have to maintain one more list and do a few more things, although the idea is similar. Note that most of the time is spend in `Transpose-Flatten` in your method, since the sublists of AK6 are unpacked.

Comment: @Leonid I know, but this was the fastest I could get with a reasonable effort (although what "reasonable effort" achieves depend on the person exerting the effort!)

Comment: +1. But, if you compare, you should also include compilation time in your case! (I only have to generate the function once). You code *is* somewhat faster, but for a different reason, which I outlined above, and to see that, you have to work on packed list, e.g. like I did in my answer.

Comment: @Leonid While I accept upfront that your code is faster, I do not see why I should include the compilation time of `f`, as it works for any input; `generateFastMean` would have to be rerun if I had a file with indices over 5001. But all this is splitting hair anyway. As for the packed lists, I had tried and it does not buy me any time (for this example). Perhaps I should have thought more about it but I was satisfied with this so stopped.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Well, yes, in that sense, I have to regenerate. But you also have some hard-coded numbers (like `4000` for example), and it is trivial to exclude too high indices by adding a switch to my code as well. In any case, my point was that the person who generates a function will know what limit to set so that it will serve many times without regeneration. Also, as I said, your compiled code probably *is* faster. One way to get that speedup is to consider indices real at the input, feed a 2D packed array directly as a single arg, and use `IntegerPart` inside `Compile`, as I did.

Comment: @Leonid you're right, I hardcoded the 4000 :) In any case, I think the point of both these examples is that this sort of coding can be an order of magnitude faster without much effort, even if it is inelegant.

Comment: Yes, the point is exactly this. I keep posting these inelegant but fast solutions to illustrate the "boundaries of the envelope".

Comment: @acl Are aware of the fact, that calls to `ConstantArray` are never compiled?

Comment: @halirutan yes, but `ConstantArray` here takes something like $10^{-6}$ seconds, while in the body of the function we iterate over something $10^6$ times. So I thought the main bottleneck would be the loop, not the initialization of the array.

Comment: @acl Completely right and I didn't wanted to criticize your post, sorry if this sounded differently. All I wanted was to emphasize that when `Table` or  `Array` is used, this is compiled to library code.

Comment: @halirutan I did not perceive any criticism

Answer (score 7):

I have another approach and since it is no update of my first answer, I post it separately. This one is short: We know from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/187) how to get/check compile-able functions in Mathematica. Since we can compile `Transpose`, `Sort`, `Reverse`, `Table`, `Mean`, `Tally` and `IntegerPart` we can simply write:

```
Get["tmp/ak6.mx"];
AK6P = Join @@ Map[Developer`ToPackedArray, AK6];

meanFirst = Compile[{{lst, _Real, 2}}, 
Module[{
  vals = Most[{1.0}], ids = Most[{1.0}], ptr = 1},
  {ids, vals} = Transpose[Sort[Reverse /@ lst]];
  Table[
    With[{currentMean = Mean[vals[[ptr ;; ptr + elm[[2]] - 1]]]},
      ptr = ptr + elm[[2]];
      {elm[[1]], currentMean}
    ], {elm, Tally[IntegerPart[ids]]}]
  ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
];

First[AbsoluteTiming[meanFirst[AK6P]]]

(*  0.199104 *)
```

The good thing is, that `Sort` works on tuples as expected, when the `id` is upfront. Then we use `Tally` to cluser the sorted `id`s and the we jump *cluster-wise* through the values and calculate the `Mean`.

This function has not call to `MainEvaluate` and runs completely in library code.

**Update**

As already pointed out in the comments, the code is not really superior to its non-compiled counterparts. The difference is, that even with `Compile` the code contains almost only high-level list-manipulations and is not broken down into c-like code, which is not often the case with `Compile`.

Comment: This seems a bit slower than the other compiled solutions, which is strange (maybe because of the `CopyTensor`s?).

Comment: Yes, probably. The nice thing here is IMO only, that a lot of highlevel functions are used and everything is done in compiled code.

Comment: +1 for the idea. Note however that your code, when uncompiled (top-level), runs only twice slower. This is because top-level `Sort` with default comparison function is so efficient that does not benefit from compilation *at all*. The two-fold speedup is because here `Table` *does* benefit from compilation. In this case, you can take the line `Transpose[Sort[Reverse /@ lst]]` to the top-level, compile the rest, and get identical performance.  My point is that compilation is most effective when you know which pieces will benefit from it the most. One big `Compile` should not be the goal IMO.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Yes, the problem is not one of the nicest. It's badly parallelizable and can be implemented with Tensor-transformations which are fast even without `Compile`. One advantage of having it all inside compiled code is, that you can now easily call it on several data-sets in parallel.

Comment: @halirutan Yes, that would make sense. Also, you may just use it on its own (take the C code), if you link against Wolfram RTL - so in some cases having everything inside `Compile` is good.

Answer (score 5):

Let me give one more approach which kind of divides the work to do. The core will be a `meanFirst` compiled function which takes a list of the form `{{val1, id}, {val2, id}, ...}` and calculate the mean of all `val` and returns their mean together with the `id`. When we use `Gather` as already done so by @MrWizard to take *all* input-tuples and creating sublists which all have a common `id`, then what's left to do is to map `meanFirst` over all these sublists.

```
meanFirst = Compile[{{l, _Real, 2}},
   {Mean[First[Transpose[l]]], l[[1, 2]]}, CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   Parallelization -> True, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
```

At this point we reconsider the `Map` and remember, that compiled functions which are parallelized and are `Listable` can use very fast pthread-parallelization without any explicit `Map`. How to do that? Easy, just give the compiled function a list or matrix of the argument-type it usually would get. Our `meanFirst` gets a `sublst` of type `{{val1, id}, {val2, id}, ...}`, so the only thing we need to do is to supply a list `{sublst1, sublst2, ...}` as argument and all mean-calculations are done in parallel.

Unfortunately there is one [Wermutstropfen](http://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/Wermutstropfen.html) to this approach. The supplied tensor is not allowed to be ragged, which means in this case all `sublst` need to have the same length. What we can do is `Gather` the list `{sublst1, sublst2, ...}` by the length of all `sublst` and we get `{{sbl11, sbl21, ...}, {sbl12, sbl22, ...}, ...}` where all `sblN1` have the same length. Now we can securely call `meanFirst[{sbl11, sbl21, ...}]` on all gathered sublists (meaning we `Map`).

Unfortunately, this means we get only a partial parallelization, but it is, nevertheless reasonable fast:

```
Get["tmp/ak6.mx"];
AK6P = Join @@ Map[Developer`ToPackedArray, AK6];
meanFirst /@ 
   Gather[Gather[AK6P, Equal[#1[[2]], #2[[2]]] &], 
    Length[#1] === Length[#2] &]];
```

Comment: I have a 6-core machine and your code runs roughly with the same speed as other non-compiled solutions. A little profiling tells us that most time is spent in the nested `Gather`- function (because the list unpacks), and this sort of destroys the purpose of both compilation and parallelization, in my view. In other words, the main culprit here is not a single core, but unpacking, so if you allow unpacking, no amount of parallelization (unless you have a 100 CPU machine) would give you a speed-up w.r.t the single-core compiled code that does not unpack.

Comment: you can see that it unpacks by doing `SetSystemOptions[
 "PackedArrayOptions" -> "UnpackMessage" -> True]`. I like the idea though, so you have my vote.