# Partitioning with varying partition size

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

How can I partition a list into partitions whose sizes vary? 
The length of the $k$'th partition is a function $f(k)$.

For example: if $l = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ and $f(k) = k$. Then
the partitioning $p$ would look like $p = \{\{1\},\{2, 3\},\{4,5,6\}\}$

---

In Mathematica 11.2, the builtin [`TakeList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeList.html) will do this.

Comment: [This question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/975/46) might be useful

Comment: [This discussion](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node520.html) may also be relevant.

Comment: @Leonid that's not a discussion it's a solution. :-)  (However, I believe I tested it before and it came up slower than `dynP`/`dynamicPartition` -- can you confirm for v8?)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, I can. But then, have a look at the `listSplit` function in my third post [here](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/21177b1d50b1e227/) :-)

Comment: @Leonid I'm claiming "great minds think alike" for this one. :-)  Since you're testing, how does ``Internal`PartitionRagged`` compare to `dynP`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `dynP` is about 40-50 % faster on my test: `test = Flatten[Range /@ Range[5000]];`, and then `dynP[test, Range[5000]]`, and similarly for the internal function.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard But, if we convert `test` to packed array with ``Developer`ToPackedArray``, then the internal function is a little faster. I would generally mention in your answer that for packed arrays, your function creates a ragged list where however all sublists remain packed (because `Part` does not unpack). This allows for much faster execution and vastly more efficient storage as well, even though the resulting array is ragged.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

*Update: see section three for a significant optimization.*

Reading your question again today I realize that I did *not* understand it completely the first time.  Since my existing answer is already quite long I am posting an additional answer.

This method is not as fast as `dynamicPartition` but it finally does what you asked.

```
partitionBy[L_List, func_] := Reap[partitionBy[L, func, 1, 0]][[2, 1]]

partitionBy[L_List, func_, i_, pos_] :=
  With[{x = pos + func[i]},
    partitionBy[Sow @ L[[pos + 1 ;; x]]; L, func, i + 1, x] /; x <= Length@L
  ]
```

Examples:

```
partitionBy[Range@10, # &]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10}}
> ```

```
partitionBy[Range@10, 2 &]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}}
> ```

```
partitionBy[Range@12, Mod[#, 3, 1] &]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7}, {8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}
> ```

On long lists you may need to increase `$IterationLimit`.

---

While I enjoyed writing the functional code above it seems a procedural approach is faster:

```
partitionBy2[L_List, func_] :=
 Reap[Block[{i = 1, p = 0, x, n = Length@L},
   While[
     (x = p + func[i++]) <= n,
     Sow @ L[[p + 1 ;; (p = x)]];
   ]
 ]][[2, 1]]
```

---

#### Compiled function

For considerably greater speed with compilable length-functions the following may be used:

```
partitionBy3[L_List, func_] := 
 Inner[L[[# ;; #2]] &, ##, List] & @@ 
  Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
    Module[{i = 1},
     {#[[;; -3]] + 1, #[[2 ;; -2]]} & @
       NestWhileList[# + func[i++] &, 0, # <= n &]
    ]
  ] @ Length @ L
```

Example:

```
partitionBy2[Range@1*^7, Mod[#, 17, 1] &] // Timing // First

partitionBy3[Range@1*^7, Mod[#, 17, 1] &] // Timing // First
```

> 3.76
>
> 1.014

Comment: you may be interested to see the definition of `Internal'PartitionRagged` [here in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13037147#13037147)

Comment: @Jacob Thanks, I do find that interesting.

Comment: @Xavier Certainly worth mentioning I think.  You may wish to post that as a separate answer.  I suggest you note in it however that it follows my initial and incorrect interpretation of the question, rather than what the OP actually wanted.  (The latter answered by `partitionBy`.)

Answer (score 59):

### The core solution

If I understand your question I [previously wrote a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5433867/618728) for this purpose.
The core of that function is:

```
dynP[l_, p_] := 
 MapThread[l[[# ;; #2]] &, {{0} ~Join~ Most@# + 1, #} & @ Accumulate @ p]
```

**Version 8 users have `` Internal`PartitionRagged `` which has the same syntax for the basic case.**

```
dynP[Range@6, {1, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}
> ```

```
dynP[Range@8, {3, 1, 2, 1}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7}}
> ```

---

### Extended version

*Since this answer proved popular I decided to do a full rewrite of `dynamicPartition`:*

- Shorter code with less duplication
- Better performance and lower argument testing overhead
- Partitioning of expressions with heads other than `List`

> `dynamicPartition[list, runs]` splits *list* into
>   lengths *runs*.
>
> `dynamicPartition[list, runs, All]` appends all
>   remaining elements in a single partition.
>
> `dynamicPartition[list, runs, spec1,
>   spec2, ...]` passes specifications *spec<sub>n</sub>* to `Partition` for the remaining elements.

```
dPcore[L_, p : {q___, _}] := Inner[L[[# ;; #2]] &, {0, q} + 1, p, Head@L]

dPcore[L_, p_, All] := dPcore[L, p] ~Append~ Drop[L, Last@p]

dPcore[L_, p_, n__] := dPcore[L, p] ~Join~ Partition[L ~Drop~ Last@p, n]

dynamicPartition[L_, p : {__Integer}, x___] :=
  dPcore[L, Accumulate@p, x] /; ! Negative@Min@p && Length@L >= Tr@p
```

(This code no longer uses `dynP` shown above.)

**Usage Examples:**

```
dynamicPartition[Range@12, {4, 3}, All]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10, 11, 12}}
> ```

```
dynamicPartition[Range@12, {4, 3}, 2]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7}, {8, 9}, {10, 11}}
> ```

```
dynamicPartition[h[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], {3, 1}, 2, 1, 1, "x"]
```

> ```
> h[h[1, 2, 3], h[4], h[5, 6], h[6, 7], h[7, "x"]]
> ```

### Packed arrays

Please note that one special but practically important case is when the list you want to split is a [packed array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array/), or can be converted into one. Here is an illustration. First, we create a large (and apparently unpacked) test list:

```
(test = Flatten[Range/@Range[5000]])//Developer`PackedArrayQ

(*  False  *)
```

We now split it:

```
(res = dynP[test,Range[5000]]);//AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.2939453,Null} *)
```

We can see that the sublists are, or course, unpacked as well:

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ/@res//Short

(*  
      {False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,
      <<4984>>,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False}
*)
```

Converting to a packed array admittedly takes some time:

```
test1 = Developer`ToPackedArray[test]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.1660157, Null} *)
```

But if you do some manipulations with this list many times, this will pay off. Also, often you end up with a packed list from the start. Anyway, now splitting this list is several times faster:

```
(res1 = dynP[test1,Range[5000]]);//AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.0644531,Null}  *)
```

and all the sublists are now also packed:

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ/@res1//Short

(*
   {True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,
    <<4982>>,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True}
*)
```

which has a large impact on the total memory consumption as well:

```
ByteCount/@{res,res1}

(*    {400320040,50900040}    *)
```

The technique of converting sub-lists of a ragged lists to packed form was already discussed a few times here on SE, e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/efficient-conditional-mean-on-a-large-data-set/1671#1671). In this particular case, `dynP` will do that automatically when the initial list is packed, but it is still good to keep in mind, for example to avoid accidental unpacking of sublists during whatever further processing you want to perform on the resulting ragged list.

Comment: +1 very cool! Perhaps for consistency  you could implement `dynamicPartition[Range@12, {4, 3}, None]` and/or `dynamicPartition[Range@12, {4, 3}, 0]` as well?

Comment: @Ajasja those would be reasonable extensions, but I think I'll leave it as it is since I want to focus on the core method `dynP`.  I thought it was better to copy the full function here rather than merely reference it on a separate site.

Comment: I agree, it's better to have the full answer here. For any body else reading (and for my future ref) Adding `0` and `None` is just a matter of adding `dynamicPartition[l_List, p : {_Integer?NonNegative ..}, None | 0] := 
 dynamicPartition[l, p]`

Comment: @Ajasja if you go down that road you could use `None | 0 | PatternSequence[]` and do it with one definition.

Comment: Thanks. ("`PatternSequence[]` represents a sequence of zero length.")

Comment: @Ajasja also, I didn't want to clutter the answer further, but since additional arguments are passed to `Partition` more complicated specifications are possible, e.g. `dynamicPartition[Range@20, {4, 3}, 2, 3, 1, "x"]`

Comment: I'll just note that Wizard's `dynP[]` is effectively equivalent to the prize-winning solution in the 1992 Mathematica Programming Competition in Rotterdam, with a few modifications. The actual submission used `Inner[]` instead of `MapThread[]`, but again, the algorithm is identical.

Comment: @J.M. I'm out of time for today but it looks like `Inner` is faster than `MapThread`.  I guess this function is due for a rewrite!

Comment: Sure, it used `Fold[]` and `Take[]` instead of `Accumulate[]` and `Span[]` (along with `Inner[]` as I mentioned earlier), but as I said, essentially the same method. Should be somewhere in *The Mathematica Journal* archives... look for the solution by Kris Thielemans.

Comment: @J.M. yes, truly nothing new under the sun.  [Here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1992/Nov/msg00096.html) is a reference to the competition that includes the code, and an alternative.  At least I learned a fair bit by working the problem out myself, even if I did it over ten years after the competition. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Forgot to +1 this beautifully thought-out and executed solution. Done.

Answer (score 25):

New in 11.2 is [`TakeList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeList):

```
TakeList[Range[10], {2, 3, 5}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}

Answer (score 15):

This can be implemented elegantly with [`FoldPairList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldPairList.html) and [`TakeDrop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeDrop.html) (both new in v10.2), in fact it's one of the examples in the documentation:

```
FoldPairList[TakeDrop, Range[10], {2, 3, 5}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}
> ```

```
FoldPairList[TakeDrop, Range[20], Range[5]]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}}
> ```

Answer (score 13):

This won't win any prizes for performance, but perhaps if there was a prize for using the second argument of `Split` in ways that were never intended...

```
partitionBy[list_, func_] :=
 Module[{f, i = func[1], k = 1},
  _f := i-- > 1 || (i = func[++k]);
  Split[list, f]]

partitionBy[Range@12, Mod[#, 3, 1] &]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7}, {8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}
> ```

Comment: That is an odd construction: `_f := ..`.

Comment: @rcollyer It may seem odd only because we are used to think of function definitions as if they are similar to other languages. Once we recall that they are rules, this is no more odd than the usual ones. I use this construct (`_f:=...`) from time to time too.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I see how it works, but it is still a bit brain warping, though. Not that's a bad thing, just odd to look at.

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, I agree. I first saa this, IIRC, in the book of Roman Maeder long time ago, and I had the same feeling back then.

Comment: @rcollyer, I don't often use it, but here it seemed a natural way to express that the arguments of `f` are completely irrelevant to its purpose.

Comment: Effective. Plus, I like the "abuse" of `Or`, a form I use frequently when I want to either return `True` or another value. +1

Comment: In my opinion, in this case writing `_f` is just a confusing way of writing `f[_]`. These expressions do not have the same `FullForm`, but they are the same for pattern matching, as far as I know. When writing `f[_]` it is also more clear that the definition will be added to the `DownValues` of f. `SetDelayed` wants as its first argument an expression with as its head the symbol you want to add the definition to. It is kind enough to treat `Blank[f]` as `f[Blank[]]`. But something like `x_ /; Head[x] == f := 9` does not work, which is ambiguous anyway. Nor does _:=3 work, no good head here.

Comment: `Trace[_g := 7, TraceInternal -> True, TraceOriginal -> True]` does not reveal much, but the `TraceInternal-> True` adds an additional `{g}`. Also fun: `Block[{HoldForm},
 SetAttributes[HoldForm, HoldAll];
 HoldForm[x_ /; Head[x] =!=   FullForm] := HoldForm[FullForm[x]];
 Trace[_g := 7, TraceInternal -> True, TraceOriginal -> True]
 ]`

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom, interesting point! There must be special handling so that `SetDelayed` knows you are trying to set a downvalue for `f` rather than for `Blank`. I wonder if it is even possible to set a downvalue for `Blank` (in the unlikely event that you would ever want to...)

Comment: @SimonWoods I think the only think standing in your way there is `Blank` being protected :). You can always restart your kernel ;).

Comment: I missed this answer until now.  This is some amazing code.  I'm still not making use of `Or` for flow control the way that you do, but I like it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I like using it, but I can see why people might prefer using more explicit flow control structures. Unrelated, looking at this answer, I can't understand why I used `f` rather than just putting it as a pure function in `Split`

Comment: Like I said, I'd like to use it but somehow I never do; I'll have to make a point of trying to use it I guess.  Regarding `f`, perhaps it was just the style you felt like using that day, but a quick test suggests that it is faster than the pure function (which I find a bit surprising) and also slightly faster than the form `f[__]` which some people wanted you to use, which I find less surprising as I remember seeing that behavior before.

Answer (score 10):

This is a bit different than Mr.Wizards excellent solution: it calculates the number of successively longer partitions (thus no irregular partitioning argument can be given) using the summation formula, and then does the same `Accumulate` & extract inside a `MapThread`.

```
myPartition[list_] := Module[
   {num = Ceiling[n /. First@Solve[{ n (1 + n)/2 == Length@list, n > 0}]]},
   MapThread[
    Take[list, {#2, Min[Length@list, #2 + #1 - 1]}] &,
    {Range@num, Most@FoldList[Plus, 1, Range@num]}]
   ];

myPartition@Range@20
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18, 19, 20}}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

I have created today a question which was a duplicate of this (thanks to [Pinguin Dirk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5274/pinguin-dirk)).

My attepmts are not very spophisticated but one may find them useful:

Let `f[k]` be a list of lengths:

```
l = Range[10];
p = {2, 3, 5};
```

**1**

```
Take[l, {1, 0} + #] & /@ (Partition[Prepend[Accumulate@p, 0], 2, 1])
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}

**2**

```
FoldList[{Take[#1[[ 2]], #2], Drop[#1[[ 2]], #2]} &, {1, l}, p
        ][[ ;; , 1]] // Rest
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}

Comment: Solution 1 nicely explains "the core solution" of Mr.Wizards older answer.

Answer (score 2):

A fairly pedestrian take, but I haven't seen it posted:

```
f[l_List] := Table[l[[(k (k - 1))/2 + 1 ;; (k (k + 1))/2]],
{k, 1, Floor[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 Length@l])]}]
```