# Binning sequential sets of elements together in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a list of the form:

```
list={{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10},{11,12},{13,14,15,16},{17,18,19,20,21,22,23},{24},{25,26},{27},{4}}
```

How can I bin each sequential set of `n` elements of the list together?  For example, if `n = 3`, we would transform the above list into:

```
{{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24},{25,26,27,4}}
```

of length 3.

Comment: You could use `Partition` and `Join`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks So apply Partition with the desired value of N, and then flatten each of the new elements?

Comment: e.g. like so: `Join @@@ Partition[list, 3]`, but depends a lot on what you plan to do

Comment: @b.gatessucks Is there an easy command to apply Flatten[ ,1] to each element in the list?

Comment: @PinguinDirk Ah, I see, that makes sense.

Comment: Using `Flatten`, it'd be like: `Flatten /@ Partition[list, 3]`. But again, not knowing where you are headed, it's hard to provide a "real" answer

Comment: @PinguinDirk Your suggestion Join @@@ Partition[list, 3] was the answer to my question as far as I'm concerned, unless you're aware of a faster way to proceed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let

```
list={{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10},{11,12},{13,14,15,16},
       {17,18,19,20,21,22,23},{24},{25,26},{27},{4}}
```

Thanks to @b.gatessucks, you could either:

```
 Join @@@ Partition[list, 3]
```

or

```
 Flatten /@ Partition[list, 3]
```

both return:

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
>      20, 21, 22, 23, 24}, {25, 26, 27, 4}}

Note that depending on the initial structure of `list`, maybe "unexpected" results might occur, e.g. try the following (dropping the last element, i.e. `{4}`):

```
Flatten /@ Partition[Most@list, 3]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
>      20, 21, 22, 23, 24}}

Why? `Most@list`now only has 8 elements, thus it is hard to partition in groups of three. By standard, `Partition` only returns the "full" (i.e. consisting of 3 elements) lists.

To react, you could e.g. use:

```
Flatten /@ Partition[Most@list, 3, 3, 1, {}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
>      20, 21, 22, 23, 24}, {25, 26, 27}}

See the documentation of [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html) for more information.

Also, check out the [dynP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7511/partitioning-with-varying-partition-size/7512#7512) function by Mr.Wizard!

Answer (score 4):

Try!

```
Partition[Flatten@#1, #2, #2, 1, {}] & @@ {list, 12}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Partition[list, 3, 3, 1, {}, Join]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12},
>     {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24},
>     {25, 26, 27, 4}}

Also

```
BlockMap[Flatten, list,3]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12},
>     {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24},
>     {25, 26, 27, 4}}

Comment: Thanks for bringing `BlockMap` to my attention. (+1)

Comment: @Edmund, thank you for the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The OP includes a 9-element list:

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 
   16}, {17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23}, {24}, {25, 26}, {27}, {4}}
```

For dividing the number `9` it into bins, consider:

```
QuotientRemainder[
    Length@list, #] /. {a_, b_} :> {Sequence @@ ConstantArray[#, a], 
     If[b != 0, b, Nothing]} & /@ Range[5]

{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 
  1}, {5, 4}}
```

Define a function to `Catenate` `n` lists together using `TakeList`:

```
nCatenate[list_List, n_Integer] :=
 Catenate /@ 
  TakeList[list, 
   QuotientRemainder[Length@list, 
     n] /. {a_, b_} :> {Sequence @@ ConstantArray[n, a], 
      If[b != 0, b, Nothing]}]

nCatenate[list, 3]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
> 20, 21, 22, 23, 24}, {25, 26, 27, 4}}

```
nCatenate[list, 2]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}, {17, 18,
> 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24}, {25, 26, 27}, {4}}

One can decide if the last (left over) items are to be kept.

---

*Addendum*

Another way of realizing sublist counts as shown above can be:

```
ips = IntegerPartitions[9]
Last /@ (MaximalBy[ips, Count[#]] & /@ Range[5])
```

> {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, 3}, {4, 4,
> 1}, {5, 1, 1, 1, 1}}