# Exporting data extensions in fits file

Tags: export, import, fits-format

**Context**

In Astronomy the de facto standard for images and data is [`FITS`](http://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov).
I would like to export heterogenous data sets into a single fits file.

**Attempt**

I am interested in exporting into a fits file some data, say.

```
 dat = Table[i, {i, 5}]
```

(* {1,2,3,4,5} *)

and additionally some metadata, say a range of $\nu$s:

```
 rnus = ("nu" <> ToString[#] -> 0.5 + # & /@ ( Range[5]))
```

(*  {nu1->1.5,nu2->2.5,nu3->3.5,nu4->4.5,nu5->5.5} *)

Following closely the documentation I can write:

```
 Export["image.fits", {"Data" -> dat, 
 "Metadata" -> Join[rnus, {"Object" -> "something"}]}, "Rules"]
```

(* image.fits *)

and read back accordingly both the data:

```
 Import["image.fits", "RawData"][[1]]
```

(* {1,2,3,4,5} *)

and the metadata:

```
  "NU1" /. Import["image.fits", "Metadata"]
  "OBJECT" /. Import["image.fits", "Metadata"]
```

(* 1.5 *)
(* Something *)

BUT, what I would like to do is to write different (large) tables of different sizes 
into a single fits file. So using a single keyword for each element is unrealistic.

If the table were of the same size I could join them into a single list, as in

```
   Export["image.fits", {"Data" -> {dat,dat}}, "Rules"]
```

but in my case the tables are not of the same size.

In principle the documentation says *"For FITS files that contain multiple images or data extensions, the above elements are taken to be lists of the respective expressions."*

**Question**

> How can I write  multiple images or data extensions into a unique fits file?
>   Or in other words, what does the documentation mean?

**Update**

As requested, here is an example of fits with an extension containing {1,2,3,4,5}
and {1,2,3,4,5,6} :

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/659996/test.fits

or it can be produced in python as

```
python
import pyfits
import numpy
data=numpy.array([1.,2.,3.,4.,5.])
pyfits.writeto("test.fits",data)
data=numpy.array([1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.])
pyfits.append("test.fits",data)
exit
```

Comment: I'm looking forward to see the answers :) I have a question, do you know how to import multidimensional fits files into MMA? I mean, one file with multiple images for example. I was never able to do this.

Comment: @Kuba No but it would have been my next question. Let's try and trigger some interest from WRI...

Comment: Wolfram Community is a good place for this but I'm not particiating there, one addiction is enough ;)

Comment: my wag you will need to directly `Write` the file rather than `Export`  http://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/fits_primer.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark but this general approach may work with a bit of tweaking.  (note another edit fix..)

```
 dat = Table[i, {i, 5}]
 rnus = ("nu" <> ToString[#] -> 0.5 + # & /@ (Range[5]))
 BinaryWrite[g = OpenWrite["test.fits", BinaryFormat -> True],
          ExportString[{"Data" -> dat, "Metadata" -> Join[rnus,
             {"Object" -> "something", "NEXTEND" -> 1}]}, {"FITS", "Rules"}]]
 BinaryWrite[g,                      
     StringReplace[
         ExportString[
             {"Data" -> dat, 
                "Metadata" -> Join[rnus, {"Object" -> "something"}]}, 
                  {"FITS",  "Rules"}], 
               "SIMPLE  =                    T" -> 
               "XTENSION= 'IMAGE   '          "]]
  Close[g];
```

Edit -- note that `StringReplace` *must* preserve the string length.

Here's what my reader shows (changing the data type to integer) .. note mathematica has added a bunch of extra metadata compared to the example.

[image]

### Approach 2

This is a more low level approach, forgoing `Export`

```
 stringpad[s_, n_] := StringJoin[s, Table[" ", {n - StringLength@s}]];
 writefitshead[f_][hdat_] := (
    BinaryWrite[f, stringpad[StringJoin[stringpad[#[[1]], 8],
      If[Length[#] > 1, StringJoin["= ", #[[2]], " "], ""],
      If[Length[#] > 2, StringJoin["/", #[[3]]], ""]], 80]] & /@ hdat;
    BinaryWrite[f, stringpad["", 80]] & /@ Range[ 36 - Length[hdat]];)
 bytelen["Real64"] = 8;
 bytelen["Integer16"] = 2;
 bytelen["Integer8"] = 1;
 writefitsdat[f_, type_][dat_] := ( 
    BinaryWrite[f, dat, type, ByteOrdering -> 1] ;
    BinaryWrite[f, 
       Table[0, {i, 2880 - Mod[Length[dat]  bytelen[type], 2880]}], "Integer8"] );
 f = OpenWrite["mytest.fits", BinaryFormat -> True];
 writefitshead[f]@{
    {"SIMPLE", "T", "conforms to FITS standard "},
    {"BITPIX", "-64", "array data type"},
    {"NAXIS", "1", " number of array dimensions"},
    {"NAXIS1", "5"},
    {"EXTEND", "T"},
    {"END"}};
 writefitsdat[f, "Real64"]@Table[i, {i, 5}]; (*note the type here has to match BITPIX*)
 writefitshead[f]@{
    {"XTENSION", "'IMAGE   '", "Image extension "},
    {"BITPIX", "-64 ", " array data type  "},
    {"NAXIS", "1", "number of array dimensions"},
    {"NAXIS1", "6"},
    {"PCOUNT", "0", "number of parameters"},
    {"GCOUNT", "1"},
    {"END"}};
 writefitsdat[f, "Real64"]@Table[i, {i, 6}];
 Close[f];
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I am not yet able to access the second table but will try again later.

Comment: what are you using to try to read it? This is a tough problem to work without access to an external application that reads the format.

Comment: based on the example I changed the XTENSION type to IMAGE -- see if that does it.

Comment: This  seems to do the trick; with ` dat2 = Table[i, {i, 6}]` and `"Data" -> dat2` in the second write. Pity its not directly available in `Export`.

Answer (score 4):

This reads your example: a crude start anyway, i'm not parsing the headers just showing them as  strings.

```
 f = OpenRead["test.fits", BinaryFormat -> True];
 First@Last@
     Reap[ While[ (Sow[
          StringJoin@BinaryRead[f, Table["Character8", {80}]]] != 
           StringJoin["END", Table[" ", {77}]])] ]
 Print["lines read = ", nh = Length[%]]
 BinaryRead[f, Table["Byte", {2880 - Mod[nh 80, 2880]}]];
```

manually set the data type and length: it looks like "BITPIX = -64" denotes  64 bit floats.
Obviously you need to parse the headers to automate this. On the next line the first arg to `Mod` is 5 values * 8 bytes

```
 BinaryRead[f, Table["Real64", {5}], ByteOrdering -> 1]
 BinaryRead[f, Table["Byte", {2880 - Mod[5 8, 2880]}]]; 

 First@Last@
    Reap[ While[ (Sow[
       StringJoin@BinaryRead[f, Table["Character8", {80}]]] != 
            StringJoin["END", Table[" ", {77}]])] ]
 Print["lines read = ", nh = Length[%]]
 BinaryRead[f, Table["Byte", {2880 - Mod[nh 80, 2880]}]];
```

again manually set the length/type

```
 BinaryRead[f, Table["Real64", {6}], ByteOrdering -> 1]
 Close[f]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I put here a function built from @george2079's answer as it may  be of interest to other people.

```
Clear[FitsExport];
FitsExport[fname_, dats_, descriptions__] :=
Module[{g},
  BinaryWrite[g = OpenWrite[fname, BinaryFormat -> True], 
  ExportString[{"Data" -> dats[[1]], 
  "Metadata" -> {"Field" -> descriptions[[1]], 
   "NEXTEND" -> 1}}, {"FITS", "Rules"}]];
  If[Length[dats] > 1,
  Do[
   BinaryWrite[g, StringReplace[
   ExportString[{"Data" -> dats[[i]], 
     "Metadata" -> {"Field" -> descriptions[[i]]}}, {"FITS", "Rules"}], 
   "SIMPLE  =                    T" -> 
    "XTENSION= 'IMAGE   '          "]],
    {i, 2, Length[dats]}];, ""];
  Close[g];
  ]

  FitsExport[fname_, dats_] :=FitsExport[fname, dats, Table[" ", {Length[dats]}]];
```

And as an example:

```
FitsExport["test.fits", 
  {Range[5], Table[i + j + 0.5, {i, 2}, {j, 3}], Range[3] + 0.5},
  {"a", "b", "c"}
 ]
```

Note that mathematica's `Import` actually works on such file:

```
   u = Import["test.fits", "RawData"];
```

(* {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {{2.5, 3.5, 4.5}, {3.5,  4.5, 5.5}}, {1.5, 2.5, 3.5}} *)

Note finally that one can use fits files to import multiple tensors and their 
name and use mathematica to do the assignment on the fly as follows.

```
 Options[FitsImport] = {SetVariables -> False};
  SetVariables::usage = "SetVariables is an option for FitsImport;
  if set the variables names are set from the fits file using the field FIELD;
  default value is False";

 FitsImport::usage = 
 "dat=FitsImport[fname]; read into the extented fits file fname;
  FitsImport[fname,SetVariables\[Rule] True] set variables from \
  extended fits file fname, using as variable name the content of 
  the field FIELD; WARNING it will override existing names";

  FitsImport[fname_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{var, head,dat},
  head = Import[fname, "Metadata"];       
  var = Select[Flatten["FIELD" /. head], StringQ];
  var // TableForm // Print;
  dat = Import[fname, "RawData"];
  If[OptionValue[SetVariables],
    Clear /@ var;
   Do[Set[Evaluate@ ToExpression[var[[i]]], dat[[i]]], {i, Length[var]}]; ,
    dat]
   ]
```

So that

```
   FitsImport["test.fits", SetVariables -> True]
```

(* a, b, c *)

```
    a
```

(* {1,2,3,4,5}  *)

Clearly for the assignment to be operational the descriptors of the field must be possible variable names. So `AGivenName` is ok, but `A Given Name` is not for instance.
Once again, when `SetVariables` is set to `True` the corresponding variables are cleared first, so beware of side effects.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

I use Mr.Wizard [`dynamicPartition`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7511/partitioning-with-varying-partition-size/7512#7512) (code included below).

```
dat1 = Range@5;
dat2 = Range@6;
metadata = {
   "MetaInfo" -> "MyData",
   "MyValue" -> ToString[Dimensions /@ {dat1, dat2}]
   };
Export["foo.fits", {"Data" -> Flatten@{dat1, dat2}, "Metadata" -> metadata}, "Rules"];
```

Example 1:

```
data = Import["1Example.fits", "RawData"]
(*
  {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}
*)

dims = "MYVALUE" /. Import["1Example.fits", "Metadata"] // ToExpression
(*
  {{5}, {6}}
*)

dynamicPartition[First@data, Times @@@ dims]
(*
  {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}
*)
```

Example 2:

```
m1 = Import["http://exampledata.wolfram.com/messier61.fits.gz", "RawData"];
m2 = Import[
   "http://www.atnf.csiro.au/people/mcalabre/data/WCS/1904-66_ARC.fits.gz", "RawData"];

metadata = {
   "MetaInfo" -> "MyData" ,
   "DataSets" -> 2, 
   "MyValue" -> ToString[Dimensions /@ First /@ {m1, m2}]
   };
Export["foo.fits", {"Data" -> Flatten@{m1, m2}, "Metadata" -> metadata}, "Rules"];

data = Import["foo.fits", "RawData"];
dims = "MYVALUE" /. Import["foo.fits", "Metadata"] // ToExpression;

{n1, n2} = MapThread[
   ArrayReshape, {dynamicPartition[First@data, Times @@@ dims], dims}];

{n1} == m1
{n2} === m2
(* 
  True
  True
*)
```

---

Mr.Wizard's code, included for convenience:

```
dPcore[L_, p : {q___, _}] := 
 Inner[L[[# ;; #2]] &, {0, q} + 1, p, Head@L]

dPcore[L_, p_, All] := dPcore[L, p]~Append~Drop[L, Last@p]

dPcore[L_, p_, n__] := dPcore[L, p]~Join~Partition[L~Drop~Last@p, n]

dynamicPartition[L_, p : {__Integer}, x___] := 
 dPcore[L, Accumulate@p, x] /; ! Negative@Min@p && Length@L >= Tr@p
```

Comment: Thank you for your attempt. It seems like  a solution, as long as the length of dat1 and dat2 are comparable; but if dat2, say , is much shorter it is a bit of a waste?

Comment: Yes, it's a waste of space.  Do you have an example of a FITS file where the sizes are different?  Say one available online?  I couldn't find one, but I don't deal with FITS regularly.

Comment: I ll get you one.

Comment: @Chris The update does not waste space, but, like my other one, it must be a nonstandard solution.

Comment: Thanks again. It does deal with the original challenge. Indeed it is not standard which would make reading in the data in other language a bit cumbersome.

Comment: @chris Thanks for adding the link.  I can't figure out anything better than george2079.  Best of luck.