# HEALPix grid on a sphere

Tags: grid-layouts, astronomy

Are there any Mathematica tools for using the HEALPix ( Hierarchical Equal Area isoLatitude Pixelation) grid on a sphere? It is commonly used in astronomy, but I have not found any Mathematica implementation of it.

Comment: You could try to add more information / links on the algorithm (and if applicable, sample data) to make researching your question more comfortable for interested users.

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13361/1089 http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58606/1089

Comment: Here's [article with description](http://iopscience.iop.org/0004-637X/622/2/759/pdf/61342.web.pdf)

Comment: There is a c library one could link to using mathlink.  It requires writing the wrapper