# How can I construct a distance table?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a list of city names (of arbitrary length), f.e.

```
c = {"BAL", "NYC", "LAS", "AUS"};
```

and the distances between them :

```
d = {232, 318, 467, 285, 670, 530};
```

With

```
m = (Flatten /@ Transpose[{c, DiagonalMatrix@Table["x", {Length@c}]}])~Prepend~({""}~Join~c)
```

I get:

[image]

Now, misusing `Mathematica` as a typewriter:

```
m[[2, 3]] = d[[1]];
m[[2, 4]] = d[[2]];
m[[2, 5]] = d[[3]];
m[[3, 2]] = d[[1]];
m[[3, 4]] = d[[5]];
m[[3, 5]] = d[[6]];
m[[4, 2]] = d[[2]];
(* etc. *)
```

I get:

[image]

1st question: How can I automate this?

2nd question: How can I get a graph of these distances?

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: How are cities and distances correlated?

Comment: @YvesKlett - The correlation is 1->2, 1->3, 1->4, 2->3, 2->4 and 3->4

Comment: Reminds me of this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5307/fill-upper-triangular-matrix-from-a-list

Comment: Also this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7511/12

Comment: Depending on the application, you might consider storing the coordinates of the cities instead and defining a metric (distance function) that takes two sets of coordinates and spits out the distance.

i.e. if you're looking literally at the bird's eye distance between cities, you could store the latitude/longitude of the cities and use a function to calculate the distances from there and fill in the table.

Comment: Do you always supply the distances or do you want to get them elsewhere? If you were supplying a full distance matrix, the rest would be trivial.

Comment: @YvesKlett - I always have (start with) c and d and I also know the correlation (like above). So, my only problem is: how can I bring the distances in the grid.

Comment: So BAL->NYC != NYC->BAL etc.? And why not a zero on the diagonal?

Comment: @YvesKlett - No, The distance between New York and Baltimore should be equal to the distance between Baltimore and New York.

Comment: The matrix you've entered manually does not match up with the city-distance correlation you've stated above.

Comment: @Myridium - BAL->NYC (1->2) = 232, BAL->LAS (1->3) = 318 ... LAS->AUS (3->4) = 530. What do I overlook here?

Comment: Look at your second image, it says BAL->NYC =232, but NYC->BAL=285

Comment: @blochwave - sorry, that was a typing error - I have corrected the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
d = {232, 318, 467, 285, 670, 530};
c = {"BAL", "NYC", "LAS", "AUS"};
```

Assuming that the `n(n-1)/2` elements in the distance list `d` 
correspond to the upper triangular part of the distance matrix for 
the given ordering of the cities, let

```
sA = SparseArray[Thread[Subsets[Range[Length@c], {2}] -> d], {Length@c, Length@c}];


sA // Normal // TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {c, c}] &
```

[image]

To get the full matrix just add `sA` and its transpose:

```
sA + sA\[Transpose] // Normal // TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {c, c}] &
```

[image]

**Using `WeightedAdjacencyGraph` with coordinates based on multi-dimensional scaling:**

I use a modification of the code from [this Demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MultidimensionalScaling/) to get the vertex coordinates that respect the distances in our distance matrix:

```
ClearAll[mDS]; 
mDS[dm_] := Module[{dims = Dimensions[dm], em = - dm dm/2, ctr, 
                    vsdvF = #[[1]].Sqrt[#[[2]]].Transpose[#[[1]]] &}, 
              ctr = IdentityMatrix[dims[[1]]] - ConstantArray[1/dims[[1]], dims]; 
             N@Transpose[vsdvF@SingularValueDecomposition[ctr.em.ctr]][[All, ;; 2]]];

dm = sA + sA\[Transpose];
vcoords = mDS[dm];
scldcoords = Transpose[Rescale /@ Transpose@vcoords];
dm = (Normal[dm]) /. (0) -> Infinity; 

options = {VertexShapeFunction -> "Square", VertexSize -> {16, 8}, 
           VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
           VertexStyle -> Hue[0.1, 0.5, 1.], AspectRatio->1,
           VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial", 16], 
           ImageSize -> 380, ImagePadding -> 20, DirectedEdges -> True,
           EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Blue, Arrowheads[{{.05, .75}}]]}; 

WeightedAdjacencyGraph[c, dm, options, VertexCoordinates -> scldcoords]
```

[image]

... and using actual coordinates from `CityData`:

```
 cities = {{"Baltimore", "Maryland", "UnitedStates"}, 
           {"NewYork",  "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}, 
           {"LasVegas", "Nevada",  "UnitedStates"},
           {"Austin", "Texas", "UnitedStates"}};
 vcoords2 = Reverse@CityData[#, "Coordinates"] & /@ cities;
 scldcoords2 = Transpose[Rescale /@ Transpose@vcoords2];

 WeightedAdjacencyGraph[c, dm, options, VertexCoordinates -> scldcoords2]
```

[image]

Comment: cheerfully accepted. I will certainly have a close look at "SparseArray" which I didn't use so far.

Comment: @eldo, thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 5):

Since other methods are already taken:

```
c = {"BAL", "NYC", "LAS", "AUS"};
d = {232, 318, 467, 285, 670, 530};

n = Length@c;

max = Binomial[n, 2];

f1 = FoldList[Subtract, max, #] &;

m = MapThread[d[[# ;; #2]] &, f1 /@ Range[{2, 1}, n - {1, 2}]] // Reverse;
m = ArrayPad[PadLeft[#, n] & /@ m, {{0, 1}, 0}];
m + m\[Transpose] // MatrixForm
```

So much for terse coding, but hopefully it's reasonably efficient. :^)

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard - Thank you very much. Your "Binomial" is very useful for me when I want to test whether the two initial lists "match". It also answers - quite unexpectedly - another of my beginner-questions: How to map an anonymous functions to another anonymous function ( f1, m) when slots are already "occupied".

Answer (score 4):

Another way, showcasing `` Internal`PartitionRagged ``:

```
upper = Join[
  PadLeft[#, Length[c]] & /@ 
   Internal`PartitionRagged[d, Reverse@Range[Length[c] - 1]],
  {ConstantArray[0, Length[c]]}
  ];
upper + Transpose@upper // TableForm
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure as how the rule extends to other examples, but this replicates your matrix

```
c = {"BAL", "NYC", "LAS", "AUS"}; 
d = {232, 318, 467, 285, 670, 530};
e = Flatten@Table[d[[j]], {i, 1, Length@c}, {j, i, Length@d}];
k = 0; Table[
 If[i == j || k >= 2 Length@c - 1, 0, k = k + 1; e[[k]]], {i, 
  Length@c}, {j, Length@c}]

(*{{0, 232, 318, 467}, {285, 0, 670, 530}, {318, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I don't have time to answer this thoroughly, but observe:

```
d = {232, 318, 467, 285, 670, 530};

DistMatrix[d_, NumCities_] := Block[{i, l},
   Return[(# + Transpose@#) &[
      Append[
       Normal@SparseArray[
         Flatten[Table[
            Table[{i, l + i}, {l, 1, NumCities - i}], {i, 1, 
             NumCities - 1}], 1] -> d]
       , Table[0, {NumCities}]]]
     ];
   ];

DistMatrix[d,4]
```

> ```
> {{0, 232, 318, 467}, {232, 0, 285, 670}, {318, 285, 0, 530}, {467, 670, 530, 0}}
> ```

This is the same as the desired matrix if you view it in TraditionalForm.

Answer (score 2):

```
c = {"Baltimore", "New York", "Las Vegas", "Austin"};

n = Length[c];

pos = Flatten[
   Table[{i, j}, {i, n - 1}, {j, i + 1, n}],
   1];

d = ToExpression[
    StringDrop[
     WolframAlpha[
      "distance between " <> #[[1]] <> 
       " and " <> #[[2]], {{"Result", 1}, 
       "Plaintext"}], -6]] & /@
   (c[[#]] & /@ pos)

{170.2, 2111, 1348, 2242, 1514, 1091}

m = Module[{mat, pts},
   mat = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];
   ReplacePart[mat, Join[
     Thread[pos -> d],
     Thread[(Reverse /@ pos) -> d]]]];

TableForm[m, TableHeadings -> {c, c}]

WolframAlpha[
 "plot of " <> StringJoin[Riffle[c, ", "]],
 {{"Path:CityData", 1}, "Content"}]
```

Comment: This throws several `ToExpression::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed .` messages here and mainly fills the table with `$Failed`.

Comment: @YvesKlett - Same with me

Comment: Code works in version 9.0.1 on my Mac

Comment: For some reason, on Win7 64bit and 9.01 the `StringDrop` part mangles the W|A output. A working alternative is: `d = StringSplit[
     StringDrop[
      WolframAlpha[
       "distance between " <> #[[1]] <> 
        " and " <> #[[2]], {{"Result", 1}, "Plaintext"}], 
      0]][[1]] & /@ (c[[#]] & /@ pos)`

Answer (score 2):

Using `GroupBy` and `Dataset` as display function:

```
d = {232, 318, 467, 285, 670, 530};
c = {"BAL", "NYC", "LAS", "AUS"};

table = Join[#, MapAt[Reverse, #, {All, 1}]] & [Thread[{Subsets[c, {2}], d}]];
```

I borrowed the following two lines from @Edmund

([Analyzing football games (pairing matrix)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/290023/analyzing-football-games-pairing-matrix))

```
zeros = Join[table, {{#, #}, 0} & /@ c];

result = 
  KeySort @ Map[KeySort] @ GroupBy[zeros, {First @* First, Last @* First -> Last}, First];

result // Dataset
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Using `ReplaceList`:**

```
d = {232, 318, 467, 285, 670, 530}; 
c = {"BAL", "NYC", "LAS", "AUS"};

lut = First /@ PositionIndex[c]
```

> <|"BAL" -> 1, "NYC" -> 2, "LAS" -> 3, "AUS" -> 4|>

```
d2 = Thread[ReplaceList[c, {___, x_, y__, ___} :> {x, Last@{y}}] -> d];

d3 = Thread[ReplaceList[c, {___, x_, y__, ___} :> {Last@{y}, x}] -> d];

dm = Join[d2, d3] /. lut // SparseArray // Normal

dm // TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {c, c}] &
```

[image]