# Analyzing football games (pairing matrix)

Tags: matrix, associations, algorithm

I want to cross-tabulate football games over several years.

**Setting up example pairings:**

Please note that there can be up to 20 clubs and a couple of thousand matches!

```
teams = {"Arsenal", "Brighton", "Chelsea"};
n = 30; (* number of matches *)

SeedRandom[0];
games = RandomChoice[Permutations[teams, {2}], n]
```

{{"Chelsea", "Brighton"}, {"Arsenal", "Chelsea"}, {"Arsenal",
"Brighton"}, {"Chelsea", "Arsenal"}, {"Arsenal",
"Brighton"}, {"Chelsea", "Arsenal"}, {"Arsenal",
"Chelsea"}, {"Brighton", "Arsenal"}, {"Arsenal",
"Chelsea"}, {"Arsenal", "Brighton"}, {"Brighton",
"Chelsea"}, {"Brighton", "Chelsea"}, {"Chelsea",
"Arsenal"}, {"Brighton", "Arsenal"}, {"Arsenal",
"Brighton"}, {"Chelsea", "Arsenal"}, {"Arsenal",
"Chelsea"}, {"Brighton", "Chelsea"}, {"Arsenal",
"Brighton"}, {"Brighton", "Chelsea"}, {"Chelsea",
"Arsenal"}, {"Arsenal", "Chelsea"}, {"Brighton",
"Arsenal"}, {"Chelsea", "Brighton"}, {"Brighton",
"Arsenal"}, {"Brighton", "Arsenal"}, {"Arsenal",
"Chelsea"}, {"Brighton", "Arsenal"}, {"Brighton",
"Chelsea"}, {"Arsenal", "Chelsea"}}

It should be noted that (unlike a yearly league) games per team might be different:

Chelsea has played 19 games (over several years),

```
Total @ Cases[{x : {_, _}, c_} /; MemberQ[x, "Chelsea"] :> c] @ Tally @ games
```

19

but Arsenal had 23 matches.

**Awarding points:**

```
SeedRandom[0];
points = RandomChoice[{3, 1, 0}, n];
```

{0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 1}

```
games = Transpose[{games, points}];
```

If there is a draw both teams must get 1 point:

```
draws = games /. {{a_String, b_}, 1} :> Splice[{{{a, b}, 1}, {{b, a}, 1}}];
```

For a lost game the other team must get three points:

```
data = draws /. {{a_String, b_}, 0} :> Splice[{{{a, b}, 0}, {{b, a}, 3}}] // Sort
```

{{{"Arsenal", "Brighton"}, 0}, {{"Arsenal", "Brighton"},
1}, {{"Arsenal", "Brighton"}, 1}, {{"Arsenal", "Brighton"},
3}, {{"Arsenal", "Brighton"}, 3}, {{"Arsenal", "Brighton"},
3}, {{"Arsenal", "Brighton"}, 3}, {{"Arsenal", "Chelsea"},
0}, {{"Arsenal", "Chelsea"}, 0}, {{"Arsenal", "Chelsea"},
0}, {{"Arsenal", "Chelsea"}, 1}, {{"Arsenal", "Chelsea"},
1}, {{"Arsenal", "Chelsea"}, 3}, {{"Arsenal", "Chelsea"},
3}, {{"Arsenal", "Chelsea"}, 3}, {{"Arsenal", "Chelsea"},
3}, {{"Arsenal", "Chelsea"}, 3}, {{"Brighton", "Arsenal"},
0}, {{"Brighton", "Arsenal"}, 1}, {{"Brighton", "Arsenal"},
1}, {{"Brighton", "Arsenal"}, 3}, {{"Brighton", "Arsenal"},
3}, {{"Brighton", "Arsenal"}, 3}, {{"Brighton", "Arsenal"},
3}, {{"Brighton", "Arsenal"}, 3}, {{"Brighton", "Chelsea"},
0}, {{"Brighton", "Chelsea"}, 1}, {{"Brighton", "Chelsea"},
1}, {{"Brighton", "Chelsea"}, 1}, {{"Brighton", "Chelsea"},
1}, {{"Brighton", "Chelsea"}, 3}, {{"Brighton", "Chelsea"},
3}, {{"Chelsea", "Arsenal"}, 0}, {{"Chelsea", "Arsenal"},
0}, {{"Chelsea", "Arsenal"}, 1}, {{"Chelsea", "Arsenal"},
1}, {{"Chelsea", "Arsenal"}, 3}, {{"Chelsea", "Arsenal"},
3}, {{"Chelsea", "Arsenal"}, 3}, {{"Chelsea", "Arsenal"},
3}, {{"Chelsea", "Arsenal"}, 3}, {{"Chelsea", "Brighton"},
0}, {{"Chelsea", "Brighton"}, 0}, {{"Chelsea", "Brighton"},
1}, {{"Chelsea", "Brighton"}, 1}, {{"Chelsea", "Brighton"},
1}, {{"Chelsea", "Brighton"}, 1}, {{"Chelsea", "Brighton"}, 3}}

**Expected result:**

This is as far as I got, but I couldn't find a presentable way to build a pairing matrix. Doing it manually counting the above points gives:

```
result =
  <|"Arsenal" -> <|"Rank" -> 1, "Arsenal" -> 0, "Brighton" -> 14, "Chelsea" -> 17, "Total" -> 31|>, 
   "Brighton" -> <|"Rank" -> 2, "Arsenal" -> 17, "Brighton" -> 0, "Chelsea" -> 10, "Total" -> 27|>, 
   "Chelsea" -> <|"Rank" -> 3, "Arsenal" -> 17, "Brighton" -> 7, "Chelsea" -> 0, "Total" -> 24|>|>;

result // Dataset
```

[image]

The result doesn't need to be a `Dataset` - I welcome any matrix-like solution.

Comment: Must be a mid-season result: Arsenal are top of the league

Comment: Well, that's an old problem of all random generators

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html), [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) (with the "add a column" syntax, and [`ReverseSortBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReverseSortBy.html).

With OP initial values of `teams`, `n`, `games`, and `points`,

```
gamepoints = Transpose[{games, points}] /. {
   {{a_, b_}, 0} :> {{b, a}, 3}
   , g : {{a_, b_}, 1} :> Sequence[g, {{b, a}, 1}]
   };
```

and

```
Dataset[
 pairmx =
  ReverseSortBy[#["Total"] &]@
   Query[
     All
     , <|KeySort[#], "Total" -> Total@#|> &
     ]@
    GroupBy[
     Join[gamepoints, {{#, #}, 0} & /@ teams]
     , {First@*First, Last@*First -> Last}
     , Total
     ]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Rank is same as position index. `Query` or `Part` will do.

```
Query[2, "Chelsea"]@pairmx
```

and

```
pairmx[[2, "Chelsea"]]
```

both give

> ```
> 10
> ```

Also by name

```
Query["Brighton", "Chelsea"]@pairmx
```

and

```
pairmx[["Brighton", "Chelsea"]]>
```

both give

> ```
> 10
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

One way to do it:

```
aggResults = GroupBy[data, First -> Last, Total]
```

> <|{"Arsenal", "Brighton"} -> 14, {"Arsenal", "Chelsea"} ->
> 17, {"Brighton", "Arsenal"} -> 17, {"Brighton", "Chelsea"} ->
> 10, {"Chelsea", "Arsenal"} -> 17, {"Chelsea", "Brighton"} -> 7|>

```
teamKeys = MapThread[Rule, {#, Range[Length@#]}] &[Union@Flatten@Keys@aggResults]
```

> {"Arsenal" -> 1, "Brighton" -> 2, "Chelsea" -> 3}

```
results = SparseArray[(#[[1]] /. teamKeys) -> #[[2]] & /@ Normal@aggResults] // Normal
```

> {{0, 14, 17}, {17, 0, 10}, {17, 7, 0}}

```
totals = Total /@ results
```

> {31, 27, 24}

```
ranking = # /. Thread[Reverse@Sort@# -> Range[Length@#]] &@totals
```

> {1, 2, 3}

```
header = (First /@ SortBy[teamKeys, Last])~Join~{"Totals", "Ranking"}
```

> {"Arsenal", "Brighton", "Chelsea", "Totals", "Ranking"}

```
matrix =  Transpose[{{""}~Join~(First /@ SortBy[teamKeys, Last])}~Join~Transpose[{header}~Join ~Transpose[Transpose@results~Join~{totals, ranking}]]]
matrix // TableForm
(*Output*)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Starting from your "data", we scan every element and use "Sow" to put the points in a list. "Sow" works like "first com, first served". Therefore, to get the pts in the correct order, we make some dummy entries using "Nothing".

Having the points in order, we may add them up and partition them according to the club. Then we sort the points according to the total. Finally we add the rank.

"pts" can now be displayed using "TableForm":

```
pts = Reap[Do[Sow[Nothing[], i], {i, 12}];
   Scan[Switch[#,
      {{"Arsenal", _}, _}, Sow[#[[2]], 4]; Sow[0, 1];
      Which[
       #[[1, 2]] == "Brighton", Sow[#[[2]], 2],
       #[[1, 2]] == "Chelsea", Sow[#[[2]], 3]],
      {{"Brighton", _}, _}, Sow[#[[2]], 8]; Sow[0, 6];
      Which[
       #[[1, 2]] == "Arsenal", Sow[#[[2]], 5],
       #[[1, 2]] == "Chelsea", Sow[#[[2]], 7]],
      {{"Chelsea", _}, _}, Sow[#[[2]], 12]; Sow[0, 11];
      Which[
       #[[1, 2]] == "Arsenal", Sow[#[[2]], 9],
       #[[1, 2]] == "Brighton", Sow[#[[2]], 10]]
      ] &
    , data]
   ][[2]];
pts = Partition[Total /@ pts, 4];

SortBy[pts, (-1 Last[#]) &];
pts = Transpose[Prepend[Transpose@pts, Range[Length[pts]]]];
TableForm[pts, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"Arsenal", "Brighton", "Chelsea"}, {"Rank", 
    "Arsenal", "Brighton", "Chelsea", "Total"}}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

Here is a version than can del with any number of teams:

```
teams= DeleteDuplicates[data[[All, 1, 1]]];

getpts[{{win_, loos_}, pt_}] := 
  Module[{posw = Position[teams, win][[1, 1]], 
    posl = Position[teams, loos][[1, 1]]},
   Sow[pt, 4 posw];
   Sow[pt, 4 (posw - 1) + posl];
   Sow[0, 4 (posw - 1) + posw];
   ];

pts = Reap[Do[Sow[Nothing[], i], {i, 12}];
    Scan[
     Do[Sow[Nothing[], i], {i, 4 Length[teams]}];
     getpts
     , data]
    ][[2]];
pts = Partition[Total /@ pts, 4];

SortBy[pts, (-1 Last[#]) &];
pts = Transpose[Prepend[Transpose@pts, Range[Length[pts]]]];
TableForm[pts, 
 TableHeadings -> {teams, Join[{"Rank"}, teams, {"Total"}]}]
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that there can be up to 20 teams - +1 anyway

Comment: I have added a version that can deal with any number of teams

Answer (score 4):

Assuming data is stored in a variable called `data`:

```
Block[{original = 
   Dataset @ GroupBy[Flatten /@ data, First -> Rest, 
     GroupBy[#, First -> Last, Total] &], transposed, keys},

(*Automatically add Missing on Diagonal*)
 transposed = GeneralUtilities`AssociationTranspose @ Normal @ original;
 
(*Used for placing Total / Rank*)
 keys = Normal @ Keys @ original;

(*Use Dataset Query to calculate the Total*)
 transposed["Total"] = 
  AssociationThread[keys -> Normal @ Values @ original[All, Total]];

(*Use Dataset Query to Find Ordering*)
 transposed["Rank"] = 
  AssociationThread[keys -> Normal @ original[Reverse @* Ordering, Total]];

 Dataset @ GeneralUtilities`AssociationTranspose @ transposed
 ]
```

##### Output:

[image]

Comment: Very nice! - For better readability: `Query[Transpose]@Normal@original`

Answer (score 2):

```
teams = {"Arsenal", "Brighton", "Chelsea"}; n = 30; 
SeedRandom[0]; games = RandomChoice[Permutations[teams, {2}], n]
SeedRandom[0]; points = RandomChoice[{3, 1, 0}, n]
games = Transpose[{games, points}]
```

```
games2 = Flatten[Table[Switch[g[[2]],
    0, {{Reverse[g[[1]]], 3}},
    1, {g, {Reverse[g[[1]]], 1}},
    3, {g}], {g, games}], 1]

totals = 
 Table[Total[Cases[games2, {{t, opp}, x_} -> x]], {t, teams}, {opp, teams}]
```

> {{0, 14, 17}, {17, 0, 10}, {17, 7, 0}}

```
results = 
 ReverseSortBy[
  Table[Join[{teams[[n]]}, totals[[n]], {Total[totals[[n]]]}], {n, 
    Length[teams]}], Last]

TableForm[Table[Insert[results[[n]], n, 2], {n, Length[results]}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, Flatten[Join[{"team", "rank"}, teams, {"total"}]]}]
```

[image]