# Populate an upper triangular matrix from a vector of elements

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, programming

What is the best way to populate an upper triangular (or alternatively: lower triangular or symmetric) matrix from a vector of elements?

This example input:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

should give

```
{{0, 1, 2, 3},
 {0, 0, 4, 5},
 {0, 0, 0, 6},
 {0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

or alternatively

```
{{0, 1, 2, 3}, 
 {1, 0, 4, 5}, 
 {2, 4, 0, 6}, 
 {3, 5, 6, 0}}
```

or even

```
{{0, 0, 0, 0},
 {1, 0, 0, 0},
 {2, 3, 0, 0},
 {4, 5, 6, 0}}
```

This problem has many solutions of course.  I'm looking for the best (criteria: most elegant/readable, shortest, fastest) ones.

The input has length $\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.  Consider $n$ known.  Feel free to use any version 10 functionality.

Comment: @MrWizard I hope you don't mind, I know we went through this once in the past.  Perhaps v10 has new ways. Note: I do have a number of solutions to the problem (including MrW's), but I chose not to share them in order not to bias the answers.

Comment: The elements are machine integers only? Or...?

Comment: @OleksandrR. I was thinking of a general solution, but actually I will only use machine integers in practice.  A fast solution using machine integers only will definitely be useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a semi-imperative function to create an upper-triangular array:

```
upperTriangular[v_] := upperTriangular[v, (1 + Sqrt[1 + 8*Length@v])/2]

upperTriangular[v_, n_] := Module[{i = 0}, Array[If[# >= #2, 0, v[[++i]]]&, {n, n}]]
```

The function is expressed using two definitions for a reason that will become clear in a moment.  Here it is in action:

```
upperTriangular @ Range @ 6

(* {{0,1,2,3},{0,0,4,5},{0,0,0,6},{0,0,0,0}} *)
```

If we know the square matrix size `n` ahead of time, and we intend to perform many such triangularizations, then it might be useful to precompile the transformation function.  The following function does that, using the two-argument form of `upperTriangular` to write the matrix construction code:

```
upperTriangulizer[n_Integer, type_:_Integer] :=
  Module[{v, r}
  , Quiet[With[{r = upperTriangular[v, n]}, Compile[{{v, type, 1}}, r]], Part::partd]
  ]
```

**Edit** *see the note below if this expression produces a warning*

Here it is in action:

```
upperTriangulizer[5] @ Range[10]
```

(* {{0,1,2,3,4},{0,0,5,6,7},{0,0,0,8,9},{0,0,0,0,10},{0,0,0,0,0}} *)

The result is a packed array:

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ @ %

(* True *)
```

We can control the data type of the matrix elements:

```
upperTriangulizer[4, _Real] @ Range[6]

(* {{0.,1.,2.,3.},{0.,0.,4.,5.},{0.,0.,0.,6.},{0.,0.,0.,0.}} *)
```

An interesting feature of the generated function is that it involves no loops -- the resultant matrix is created by direct construction.  The loops have been completely unrolled, a desirable situation for some applications:

```
CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint@upperTriangulizer[3, _Real]

(*
    1 argument
    4 Integer registers
    9 Real registers
    2 Tensor registers
    Underflow checking off
    Overflow checking off
    Integer overflow checking on
    RuntimeAttributes -> {}

    T(R1)0 = A1
    I0 = 0
    I2 = 2
    I1 = 1
    I3 = 3
    Result = T(R2)1

1   R0 = Part[ T(R1)0, I1]
2   R1 = Part[ T(R1)0, I2]
3   R2 = Part[ T(R1)0, I3]
4   R3 = I0
5   R4 = I0
6   R5 = I0
7   R6 = I0
8   R7 = I0
9   R8 = I0
10  T(R2)1 = {{R3, R0, R1}, {R4, R5, R2}, {R6, R7, R8}}
11  Return
*)
```

---

**Note about the warning *Optional::opdef***

*Mathematica* versions 9 and earlier issue a warning when the compiled version of `upperTriangulizer` is defined:

> Optional::opdef: "The default value for the optional argument type_:_Integer contains a pattern."

This message is defensive in nature, warning that the construction `type_:_Integer` is unusual.  So unusual, in fact, it is frequently more likely to be a typing error rather than intentional.  But in this case, the construction *is* intentional.  We are defining a function that expects a type pattern as an argument, and we are assigning `_Integer` as the default pattern.

For whatever reason, version 10 no longer issues this warning message.  Perhaps WRI is finding such constructions to be more common now?  In any event, the message is safe to suppress on earlier versions:

```
Quiet[
  upperTriangulizer[n_Integer, type_:_Integer] :=
    Module[{v, r}
    , Quiet[With[{r = upperTriangular[v, n]}, Compile[{{v, type, 1}}, r]], Part::partd]
    ]
, Optional::opdef
]
```

Comment: Why function `upperTriangulizer` cannot be executed in my Mathematica V8 enviroment correctly? It gives the warning information:`Optional::opdef: "The default value for the optional argument type_:_Integer contains a pattern."`

Comment: @Tangshutao I have added a note concerning this message to the bottom of my response.

Comment: I think you can do like `upperTriangular[v_, n_] /; Length@v == (n (n - 1))/2:=...` to omit the definition `upperTriangular[v_] := upperTriangular[v, (1 + Sqrt[1 + 8*Length@v])/2]`

Comment: @Tangshutao If I did that, it would place the burden of computing `n` on the caller and make `upperTriangular[v, n]` go inert if they got that calculation wrong.  If we wanted only one definition, I would keep `upperTriangular[n_]` and merge the second into it by computing `n` within the `Module`.  But the separate definitions support both the original use case as well as the precomputation of the transformation function by `upperTriangulizer`.

Answer (score 13):

Probably not fast, but very simple:

```
upperTriangular[elements_, n_] :=
 SparseArray[
  Thread[
    SymmetrizedIndependentComponents[{n, n}, Antisymmetric[{1, 2}]] ->    
    elements]]
```

Comment: `SymmetrizedIndependentComponents`?  These function names are getting out of hand. +1 nevertheless as I don't recall seeing that function used before.

Comment: Great!  I didn't mention it but I was hoping for something using this functionality.  Is `StructuredArray` useful here?

Answer (score 8):

**Update:** Recently bumped into `` Statistics`Library`VectorToUpperTriangularMatrix `` which, as the name suggests, seems to do just what is needed. The second argument controls the diagonal elements. The third argument seems to control the matrix dimension; I could get it to work only with appropriate integer based on the length of the first argument.

```
vecToUTM = Statistics`Library`VectorToUpperTriangularMatrix[#, #2, 
  (1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 Length@#])/2]&;

vecToUTM[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 0] // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
>  0 & 0 & 4 & 5 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 6 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
vecToUTM[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, x] // TeXForm
```

> $ \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  x & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
>  0 & x & 4 & 5 \\
>  0 & 0 & x & 6 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & x \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
vecToUTM[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} , {a, b, c, d}]
```

> $ \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
>  0 & b & 4 & 5 \\
>  0 & 0 & c & 6 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & d \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[f1];
f1 = RotateLeft[PadLeft[Internal`PartitionRagged[Range[# (#-1)/2], 
      Range[#-1, 1, -1]], {#, #}]] &;

Row[MatrixForm /@ {m1 = f1[4], Transpose[m1], m1 + Transpose[m1]}]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[f2];
f2 = With[{m = Solve[{a (a - 1)/2 == Length@#, a > 0}, a, Integers][[1, 1, 2]]},
   RotateLeft[PadLeft[Internal`PartitionRagged[#, Reverse@Range[m - 1]], {m, m}]]] &;

Row[MatrixForm/@ {m1 = f2[Range[6]], Transpose[m1], m1 + Transpose[m1]}]
```

[image]

```
lst2 = CharacterRange["a", "z"][[;;10]];
Row[MatrixForm /@ {m1 = f2[lst2], Transpose[m1], m1 + Transpose[m1]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is very efficient

Comment: @Tangshutao, it is - to my surprise- quite fast; @Chip Hurst's compiled `Matrixify` is twice as fast though. Just crashed Windows trying to do timings for the posted methods:)

Comment: Dear kguler, How can I understand `Internal-PartitionRagged`, I cannot find the usage of this function in `Wolfram Help Documentation`

Comment: @Tangshuato, _??Internal`PartitionRagged_ gives some info about the function. To see the code you can use _ClearAttributes[Internal`PartitionRagged, ReadProtected]_ followed by _??Internal`PartitionRagged_.

Answer (score 7):

I realized this is possible to implement rather cleanly using `partitionBy` as [defined here.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7808/121)
This method produces the "*or even*" form shown as the third example.

```
in = Range[6];

PadRight @ partitionBy[in, # &] ~ArrayPad~ {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  2 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
>  4 & 5 & 6 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

---

### Old answer from Code Review

[(Source)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5307)

Here are a few methods for your consideration and feedback.

All use:

```
s = 5
elems = Range[s(s-1)/2]
```

---

This one uses the core of my ["Dynamic Partition"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5433867#5433867) function.  It is the fastest method I know for this problem.  Also, perhaps refactoring the code like this makes it more intelligible.

```
dynP[l_, p_] := 
 MapThread[l[[# ;; #2]] &, {{0}~Join~Most@# + 1, #} &@Accumulate@p]

#~PadRight~s & /@ {{}} ~Join~ dynP[elems, Range[s-1]]
```

---

This one is slightly shorter, using a different way to construct the indices, but also slightly slower, and perhaps less transparent.

```
#~PadRight~s & /@ 
 Prepend[
   elems~Take~# & /@ 
     Array[{1 + # (# - 1)/2, # (# + 1)/2} &, s - 1],
   {}
 ]
```

---

This one is terse, but slow.  Legibility is debatable.

```
SparseArray[Join @@ Table[{i, j}, {i, s}, {j, i - 1}] -> elems, s] // MatrixForm
```

---

Here is one I just came up with, and I am quite pleased with it.  I think it may be more understandable than most of the ones above.

```
Take[FoldList[RotateLeft, elems, Range[0, s - 1]] ~LowerTriangularize~ -1, All, s + 1]
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a procedural, hence compilable solution:

```
Matrixify = Compile[{{lis, _Integer, 1}},
  Module[{n, mat, pl = 1, pm = 2, i = 1},

    n = Round[(Sqrt[8 Length[lis] + 1] + 1)/2];
    mat = Table[0, {n^2}];

    Do[
      mat[[pm ;; pm + k - 1]] = lis[[pl ;; pl + k - 1]];
      i++;
      pl += k;
      pm += k + i,
      {k, n - 1, 1, -1}
    ];

    Partition[mat, n]

  ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  Parallelization -> True,
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
];
```

Here are some results:

```
Matrixify[Range[6]]
(* {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 4, 5}, {0, 0, 0, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 0}} *)

Matrixify[Range[Binomial[1000, 2]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.032628, Null} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
s = 4;
lis = Range[s (s - 1)/2];
PadLeft[lis[[1 + # s - (# (1 + #))/2 ;; (1 + #) s - ((# + 1) (2 + #))/
         2]], s, 0] & /@ Range[0, s - 1] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: I think cannot apply to the list of `{a,b,c,d,e,f}`, it seems that your solution just suitable for the list of `Range[n]`

Answer (score 2):

### My trial:

**Define the function:**

```
upperTriangular[expr_?VectorQ, n_Integer] /; Length@expr == (n (n - 1))/2 := 
 Join[Table[0, {n - Length@#}], #] & /@ (Append[
   Complement[#2, #1] & @@@ 
    Partition[
      Prepend[Take[expr, #] & /@ Accumulate@Reverse@Range[n - 1], {}],2, 1], {}])
```

**Test**

```
expr1=CharacterRange["a", "u"];
upperTriangular[expr, 7] // MatrixForm
```

> $ \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  0 & \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c} & \text{d} & \text{e} & \text{f} \\
>  0 & 0 & \text{g} & \text{h} & \text{i} & \text{j} & \text{k} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & \text{l} & \text{m} & \text{n} & \text{o} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{p} & \text{q} & \text{r} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{s} & \text{t} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{u} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

**The test of OP**

```
expr2=Range@6;
upperTriangular[expr2, 4] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
>  0 & 0 & 4 & 5 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 6 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

#### Testing the  efficiency

```
upperTriangular[Range@Binomial[1000, 2], 1000]; // Timing
```

> {9.875, Null}

### Edit

**Using the `PadLeft` ,come from @Algohi's answer**

```
upperTriangular2[expr_?VectorQ, n_Integer] /; Length@expr == (n (n - 1))/2 := 
 PadLeft[#, n] & /@ (Append[
   Complement[#2, #1] & @@@ 
    Partition[
      Prepend[Take[expr, #] & /@ Accumulate@Reverse@Range[n - 1], {}],2, 1], {}])
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `TakeList`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 8;
list = Range[Binomial[n, 2]];

TakeList[list, Range[0, n - 1]] // Map[PadRight[#, n] &] // MatrixForm
TakeList[list, Range[n - 1, 0, -1]] // 
  Map[PadLeft[#, n] &] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

---

**Using `ReplacePart`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 8;
list = Range[Binomial[n, 2]];
posu = Flatten[#, 1] &@Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, n}, {j, i + 1, n}];
rulesup = Thread[posu -> list];
ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, {n, n}], rulesup] // MatrixForm

posdn = Flatten[#, 1] &@Table[{i, j}, {i, 2, n}, {j, 1, i - 1}];
rulesdn = Thread[posdn -> list];
ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, {n, n}], rulesdn] // MatrixForm
```

(* same outputs *)