# Creating lower triangle elements by conjugating of upper triangle elements

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, complex

I have generated the upper triangular elements of a matrix by some loops. Although, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56446/forming-an-upper-triangular-matrix-from-the-elements-of-a-list) deals with forming an Upper triangular matrix of a list but we want the lower triangular part elements be the conjugate of upper triangular elements. (`w`, `s` and `d` are reals but can have negative values). The first created matrix is

```
matbefore = {{s, I w - 1, 0, w - 1, I w, I d}, {0, 1 - s, w, 
0, w, I d - 1}, {0, 0, 1 + s, w I,0, w - 2}, {0, 0, 0, 1 + s, d I, 0},  {0, 0, 0 , 0, 1 - s, I d^2}, {0,0, 0, 0, 0, s}};
```

the matrix which can be represented by

```
matafter = {{s, I w - 1, 0, w - 1, I w, I d}, {Subscript[a, 21], 1 - s, w, 
0, w, I d - 1}, {Subscript[a, 31], Subscript[a, 32], 1 + s, w I, 
0, w - 2}, {Subscript[a, 41], Subscript[a, 42], Subscript[a, 43], 
1 + s, d I, 0}, {Subscript[a, 51], Subscript[a, 52], Subscript[a, 
53], Subscript[a, 54], 1 - s, I d^2}, {Subscript[a, 61], 
Subscript[a, 62], Subscript[a, 63], Subscript[a, 64], Subscript[a,
 65], s}};
```

(* I just used `Subscript[a,_]` to show the lower elements. They are zero before they will be replace with conjugated numbers.*)
[image]

For example `Subscript[a, 21]` must be `-1-w I` and `Subscript[a, 51]` must be `-w I`. Can we use of `Hermitian` property of the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the conjugate transpose to the original matrix. If you want the diagonal to remain unchanged, you also need to subtract it out.

```
FullSimplify[matbefore + Conjugate[Transpose[matbefore]] - 
  DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal[matbefore], {s ∈ Reals, w ∈ Reals, d ∈ Reals}]
```

[image]

Comment: Or just `ConjugateTranspose[matbefore]` for that part  ;=}

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure whether this is what you want, but transposing the matrix and taking the `Conjugate` of the elements should help

```
mat /. Subscript[a, _] :> 0 /. e_ :> ComplexExpand[Conjugate[e]] // Transpose
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can use `ComplexExpand` to tell that all variables `s`, `d` and `w` are real valued in the complex expressions.

Comment: So much thanks, but if we want the whole matrix we should add the previous parts with this new part?1

Comment: One problem: I just used `Subscript[a,_]` to show the lower elements. They are zero before they will be replace.