# How to fill lower trianglar matrix with elements of a vector

Tags: matrix

Given a dimension $n$ and a vector $v$ such as

```
n = 5
v = Range[n (n + 1)/2]
```

Is there any way to automate the construction of the following lower triangular matrix $X$, given arbitrary $n$ and $v$?

```
X = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 3, 0, 0, 0}, {4, 5, 6, 0, 0}, {7, 8, 9, 10, 
    0}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}} // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55659/populate-an-upper-triangular-matrix-from-a-vector-of-elements , and unfortunately, ``Statistics`Library`VectorToUpperTriangularMatrix`` doesn't have a sister function. Could use it + `Transpose[]`.

Answer (score 10):

```
PadRight[Internal`PartitionRagged[v, Range@n]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you! What if the elements of $v$ are of the form `{v[1] -> 1, v[2]->2,...}`. How can I extract the numerical values without the name `v[1]` and add them to the lower triangular matrix as you showed?

Comment: @Rudinberry If the values are in order, then `Values[list]`. Otherwise `Array[v, m] /. list`, where `m` is how many `v[k]` you have (or `Array[v, Length[list]]` if the length varies).

Comment: @Rudinberry it is better to include such extra details in your question. Can you, please, update your question with these details?

Answer (score 7):

- When the data is a list.

```
n = 5;
v = Range[n (n + 1)/2];
TakeList[v, Range[n]] // PadRight
% // MatrixForm
```

- When the data is the `Rule`

```
n = 5;
rules = Table[v[i] -> i, {i, 1, Total@Range@n}]
Values /@ TakeList[rules, Range@n] // PadRight
```

Answer (score 4):

Though there are already excellent answers by Michael and cvgmt, we still have a long way to go to ten ways of achieving the result.

Borrowing from Mr.Wizard's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7511/partitioning-with-varying-partition-size/7808#7808)

```
MatrixForm@PadRight@partitionBy[v, # &]
```

> [image: mat]

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do it:

```
MapThread[Composition[PadRight[#, n] &, Plus[#1, #2] &], {Map[Array[# &, #] &, Range[n]], MapThread[ConstantArray[#1, #2] &, {Map[1/2 (# - 1) # &, Range[n]], Range[n]}]}]
```

[image]