# Piecewise Polynomial Interpolation

Tags: interpolation, polynomials, piecewise

Given some data pairs $(x_i,y_i)$, with $i=0,...,m$, and a degree $r$, I wish to build a piecewise polynomial function to interpolate these data. That interpolation should be continuous, and, on every interval $[x_k,x_{k+r}]$, with $k=0, r, 2r, ...$, should be a polynomial of degree $r$. 
This can be useful for example to represent the solution of a PDE obtained with finite element method of degree $r$.

Because with $r=1$ there are no problem I'll refer to $r=2$. For example, given the following data pairs:

$$ \{ (0,0), (1,1), (2,0), (3,1), (4,0) \}  $$

I wish to get this result:

[image]

**The resulting interpolation function need not to have continuous derivative at $x=2$.**

I tried with Interpolation and various options:

```
Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 2, Method -> "Hermite"]
Plot[%[x], {x, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

```
Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 2, Method -> "Spline"]
Plot[%[x], {x, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

As a reference, under *MATLAB*, I can build a piecewise polynomial interpolation of arbitrary degree, in a some involved way, with `mkpp`, and later consume the interpolation with `ppval`. For piecewise linear interpolation there is a more simple and direct `interp1` function.

Under *MATLAB* I give to `mkpp` the values of the polinomials and their derivatives at $x_0, x_r, x_{2r}, ...$ and I get the expected result. Under *Mathematica* this approach doesn't work:

```
Interpolation[{{{0}, 0, 2, -2}, {{2}, 0, 2, -2}, {{4}, 0, 2, -2}}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 2, Method -> "Hermite"]
Plot[%[x], {x, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

I considered using `Piecewise` and constructiong an `Interpolation` or a polynomial pure function for every interval $[x_k,x_{k+r}]$ but I suspect this become unmanageably complex when there are hundred or thousand of intervals.

There is some builtin way, reasonably simple and fast, to get this result? Naturally I search a general way, for general data and general $r$.

### UPDATE

@kguler answer is interesting but I need a way to generalize for every $r$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At present I'm still unable to find a builtin way to do this, so I decided to write my implementation just to go on.

A set of definitions to build the polinomial coefficients are needed. The first return a function to build the coefficients for degree $r$ and grid spacing $h=1$ and remember the result. The second is for generic $h$. The third accepts also function values and returns the coefficients instead of a function to build coefficients.

```
PiecewisePolynomialCoefficients[r_Integer /; r >= 1] := 
 PiecewisePolynomialCoefficients[r] =
  Evaluate[
    Block[{x}, 
     Reverse@CoefficientList[
        InterpolatingPolynomial[Table[{i, Slot[i + 1]}, {i, 0, r}], 
         x], x] // Simplify]] &
PiecewisePolynomialCoefficients[r_Integer /; r >= 1, h_] :=
 Evaluate[
   PiecewisePolynomialCoefficients[r] @@ Array[Slot, {r + 1}]/
    Table[h^i, {i, r, 0, -1}]] &
PiecewisePolynomialCoefficients[r_Integer /; r >= 1, h_, 
  yv_?VectorQ] := 
 PiecewisePolynomialCoefficients[r, h] @@ yv /; Length[yv] == r + 1
```

The coefficients are returned from the highest order to lowest so the following function can be used to evaluate the polinomial.

```
PolynomialHornerEvaluation[coeffs_?VectorQ, x_] := 
 Fold[(#1 x + #2) &, 0, coeffs]
```

The following function do the interpolation, compute polynomial coefficients and store info in a PiecewisePolynomialInterpolatingFunction object for later evaluation.

```
Options[PiecewisePolynomialInterpolation] := {InterpolationOrder -> 1};
PiecewisePolynomialInterpolation[
  xd : {xl_, xr_} /; NumericQ[xl] && NumericQ[xr] && xl < xr,
  yv_ /; VectorQ[yv] && Length[yv] >= 2,
  OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[{r, n, h, breaks, coeffs},
  r = OptionValue[InterpolationOrder];
  n = Length[yv];
  h = (xr - xl)/(n - 1);
  breaks = Range[xl, xr, r h];
  coeffs = 
   PiecewisePolynomialCoefficients[r, h] @@@ Partition[yv, r + 1, r];
  PiecewisePolynomialInterpolatingFunction[breaks, coeffs]
  ]
```

The following function dipslay relevant info of the PiecewisePolynomialInterpolatingFunction object.

```
MakeBoxes[
   PiecewisePolynomialInterpolatingFunction[breaks : {___}, 
    coeffs : {___}], form_] :=
  With[{dom = ToBoxes@Through[{First, Last}[breaks]], 
    order = ToBoxes[Length@First@coeffs - 1], 
    nodes = ToBoxes@Length[breaks]},
      RowBox[{"PiecewisePolynomialInterpolatingFunction[", 
     StyleBox[FrameBox[GridBox[
        {{"Domain:", dom}, {"Order:", order}, {"Nodes:", nodes}}]], 
      "DialogStyle", Gray, Small], "]"}]
      ];
```

The following definition evaluate the PiecewisePolynomialInterpolatingFunction object at some specific point $x$.

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"] (* For BinarySearch *)

PiecewisePolynomialInterpolatingFunction[breaks : {___}, 
   coeffs : {___}][x_?NumericQ] :=
  With[{i = Which[
     x < breaks[[1]], Message[InterpolatingFunction::dmval, x]; 1,
     x > breaks[[-1]], Message[InterpolatingFunction::dmval, x]; 
     Length[coeffs] - 1,
     True, Floor@BinarySearch[breaks, x]
     ]},
  PolynomialHornerEvaluation[coeffs[[i]], x - breaks[[i]]]
    ]
```

This way apparently works:

[image]

Any fix to this implementation (faster, safer, more generic) is appreciated. Any builtin solution also.

Answer (score 8):

Based on [What's inside InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 4.}}, <>]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4), I would guess that a built-in way is not possible.  However, one can take advantage of `InterpolatingFunction` to construct a `Piecewise` function.  Here, `split`, does an overlapping partition starting a new list at position `p`, is a modification of [Mr.Wizard's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) `dPcore` in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7511/partitioning-with-varying-partition-size/7512#7512).

```
split[L_, pos_] := 
 Inner[L[[# - 1 ;; #2]] &, Prepend[pos + 1, 2], Append[pos, Length[L]], Head@L]

pwpolyifn[pts_, breaks_] := Function[x,
  Evaluate@
   Piecewise[{Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> All][
        x], #[[1, 1]] <= x <= #[[-1, 1]]} & /@ split[pts, breaks]
    ]]
```

Example: `split` can do a ragged split.

```
split[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {6, 0}}, {3, 6}]
(*
  {{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}},
   {{2, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}},
   {{5, 1}, {6, 0}}}
*)
```

In this one, the OP's example, `split[.., {3, 5}]` is the same as `Partition[.., 3, 2]`:

```
split[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {6, 0}}, {3, 5}]
(*
  {{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}},
   {{2, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}},
   {{4, 0}, {5, 1}, {6, 0}}}
*)

pwpolyifn[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {6, 0}}, {3, 5}][x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[pwpolyifn[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {6, 0}}, {3, 5}][x],
    {x, 0, 6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another example:

```
SeedRandom[1];
pts = Table[{i, RandomReal[{0, 10}]}, {i, 0, 20}];
breaks = {3, 8, 10, 16};
Plot[Evaluate@pwpolyifn[pts, breaks][x], {x, 0, 20}, 
 GridLines -> {pts[[breaks]][[All, 1]], None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If bullet-proofing the definition is desired, then one can check that `pts` is a list of pairs of numbers and that the breaks are increasing and lie between 2 and `Length[pts] - 1`.

Comment: Instead of `split` can't you just do `Partition[list, r+1, r]`?

Comment: @RahulNarain  Maybe I should show it for the last example.  It's similar to ``Internal`PartitionRagged``, except with the overlap like your `Partition` example.

Comment: Ah, right, one can't do the last example with `Partition`. In the original question the degree is constant, though, so `Partition` should be sufficient. +1 for the `Piecewise` and `InterpolationOrder -> All`.

Comment: What exactly `All` means as a value for the option `InterpolationOrder` of the `Interpolation` function?

Comment: @unlikely It means the degree should be as high as possible, the length of the list minus 1.  (Originally I had `Length[pts] - 1`.)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps too specific to OP's example case:

```
Interpolation[{{{0}, 0, Automatic}, {{1}, 1, 0}, {{2}, 0,  Automatic}, 
               {{3}, 1, 0}, {{4}, 0. Automatic}}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 2]
  Plot[%[x], {x, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

and

```
 Interpolation[{{{0}, 0, Automatic}, {{1}, 1, 0}, {{2}, 0,  Automatic}, 
                {{3}, 1, 0}, {{4}, 0. Automatic}}, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 2, PeriodicInterpolation -> True]
 Plot[%[x], {x, 0, 8}]
```

[image]

Comment: You're probably right -- the OP does say he wants the polynomials all the same degree.

Comment: This apperars interesting... What exactly  `Automatic` implies? The documentation is a bit lachonic. And for general $r$ and general case how should I constuct the data to pass to `Interpolation`?

Comment: @unlikely, the only info in the documentation is in the `Details` section: "Partial derivatives not specified explicitly can be given as Automatic". I will post an update, if i can figure out a generalization to arbitrary `r`.