# Derivative of contour in ContourPlot

Tags: numerics, interpolation, smoothing

Sorry to bring this question up again, since there are many similar questions on the site. I use to think this is a easy job to do, because for the worst case I can follow the answers on this site. But after several tests, I found it is not as easy as I expected.

First is the contour plot:

```
Eq = (Sinh[
       b] (80 - 80 Cos[b] + 8 b^4 Cos[b] - 8 b^4 Cos[b (1 - 2 xm)] + 
        10 b Sin[b] + 32 b^3 Sin[b] - 10 b Cosh[b] Sin[b] + 
        20 b Cosh[b/2]^2 (-1 + 2 Cosh[2 b xm]) Sin[b] - 
        20 b Sin[b (1 - 2 xm)] - 20 b Sin[2 b xm] - 
        20 b Cos[b] Sinh[b] + 20 b Cos[b (1 - 2 xm)] Sinh[b] - 
        80 Sin[b] Sinh[b] - 
        160 b Cosh[b/2] Sin[b/2] Sin[b xm] Sinh[b xm] + 
        20 b Sinh[2 b xm] - 20 b Cos[b] Sinh[2 b xm] + 
        8 b^4 Sin[b] Sinh[2 b xm] - 
        20 b Sin[b] Sinh[b] Sinh[2 b xm]) + 
     Cosh[b] (20 b - 50 b Cos[b] + 30 b Cos[b (1 - 2 xm)] + 
        10 b Cos[b] Cosh[b] - 10 b Cos[b (1 - 2 xm)] Cosh[b] - 
        120 Sin[b] + 8 b^4 Sin[b] + 40 Cosh[b] Sin[b] - 
        2 b Cosh[b xm]^2 (10 - 10 Cos[b] + 4 b^3 Sin[b]) + 
        20 b Sin[b] Sinh[b] - 20 b Cosh[2 b xm] Sin[b] Sinh[b] + 
        160 b Sin[b/2] Sin[b xm] Sinh[b/2] Sinh[b xm] - 
        20 b Sinh[b xm]^2 + 20 b Cos[b] Sinh[b xm]^2 - 
        8 b^4 Sin[b] Sinh[b xm]^2 - 30 b Sin[b] Sinh[2 b xm] + 
        10 b Cosh[b] Sin[b] Sinh[2 b xm] + 
        20 Cosh[b/2]^2 (b Cos[b] - b Cos[b (1 - 2 xm)] + 4 Sin[b] + 
           b Sin[b] Sinh[2 b xm])));

p = ContourPlot[Eq == 0, {xm, 0, 1/2}, {b, 2, 4}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

Following suggestion from Mr.Wizard♦ in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31169/11867, I set `PlotPoints` to `100`.

Then, extract the points from the plot:

```
lines = Cases[p, _Line, Infinity];
points = p[[1, 1]];
l1 = Map[Part[points, #] &, lines[[1, 1]]];
```

[image: 1]

I think the curve is pretty smooth, so I use `Interpolation` to interpolate the points:

```
Plot[Interpolation[l1]'[x], {x, 0, 0.5}]
```

[image: 2]

It is clear jitters in the data cause the derivative not smooth. Therefore, following stevenvh's advice in (http : // mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10987/11867), I reduce the `InterpolationOrder` to `2` and `1`.

```
Plot[Interpolation[l1, InterpolationOrder -> 2]'[x], {x, 0, 0.5}]
Plot[Interpolation[l1, InterpolationOrder -> 1]'[x], {x, 0, 0.5}]
```

[image: 3]
[image: 4]

It is better obviously, but not ideal. I think [answer from chris](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10997/11867) make sense, `BSpline` should be a better solution, but not for derivative.

```
bs = BSplineFunction[l1];
ParametricPlot[bs[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: 5]

```
ParametricPlot[bs'[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: 6]

After that, I recall s.s.o mentioned Wavelet can be used to smooth the data in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65590/11867, but I suddenly realize that the data points are not evenly sampled. Therefore, I try to use other smooth method, like `MovingAverage`.

```
Interpolation[MovingAverage[l1, 51], InterpolationOrder -> 2]
Plot[%'[x], {x, 0, 1/2}]
```

[image: 7]

This is pretty close to smooth curve, but not ideal. Then, I think `MovingMedian` may remove the jitter noise:

```
Interpolation[MovingMedian[l1, 15], InterpolationOrder -> 2]
Plot[%'[x], {x, 0, 1/2}]
```

[image: 8]

But the answer is no.

I would like to narrow this problem to processing the data points in `ContourPlot`, because for this problem the derivative actually can be obtained through the analytical equation. I am curious about how to solve it by processing the data points in the figure.

### Summary

I would not like to call this a conclusion, because I think there may be a better solution out there. Untill now, we have mainly two possible solutions for this problem.

#### Low pass filter based methods

@Jens and @Michael E2 both provide a solution based on low pass filter. It should be noted `LowpassFilter` and `DifferentiatorFilter` support only even sampled data for *Mathematica* lower than v10.1:

> LowpassFilter currently only supports regularly sampled time series \
>   inputs. Use TimeSeriesResample or TemporalRegularity to make the \
>   input regularly sampled. >>

You can use code like following:

```
lp = LowpassFilter[TimeSeries@TimeSeriesResample[l1, 0.001], 0.5];
```

*Note:* the cut-off frequency in both filters will reduce the absolute value of derivative due to filter process. You should try several cut-off frequencies and make trade-off between smoothness and  the reduction.

Moreover, I find `MovingAverage` may also provide smooth result if you increase `PlotPoints` to 300. The following command provides a decent result:

```
Interpolation[MovingAverage[l1, 30], InterpolationOrder -> 2];
Plot[%'[x], {x, 0, 1/2}]
```

[image: 9]

*Note:* `MovingAverage` is also one kind of low-pass filter, and thus has the same problem as the previous two methods. However, it is fast and easy to understand.

#### Spline based methods

There are two different implementations in the answer of @Alexey Popkov.

The first one is not strictly a spline based method, the idea is interpolate the data in sub-segements, and then fit the data with `NonlinearModelFit`.

The second one is based on `QuantileRegression`, which can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction). The performance of the package looks quite decent.

BTW, the correct way to use `BSplineFunction` is shown in the comment by @Michael E2 as

```
dbs[t_?NumericQ] := First@Ratios[bs'[t]]; 
xbs[t_?NumericQ] := 
 First@bs[t]; ParametricPlot[{xbs[t], dbs[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

The above codes produce following figure for `PlotPoints->300`

[image: 10]

#### Other thoughts

Piecewise polynomial should be a candidate for this problem, but as I commented in answer of @Alexey Popkov, implementation from [Piecewise Polynomial Interpolation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56023/piecewise-polynomial-interpolation) by @Michael E2 does not provide an ideal result for this problem. `loess` in `R` handles problems similar to this one pretty well. I find one implementation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45524/11867), but I cannot make it work yet.

Currently, the best choices for this problem are `QuantileRegression`, `LowpassFilter` and `MovingAverage`.

Comment: You'll need to smooth further. You may try `ND[ ]` with higher `Terms` option or some filter like `GaussianFilter[ ]`

Comment: I agree that this is probably a smoothing problem, but I also wonder: your `l1` variable has exactly the same value as your `points` variable. Also, have you looked at the contents of `lines`? It is quite uninteresting as well. Are those expressions really doing what you want them to do?

Comment: @MarcoB for this case, `l1` and `points` are same, but if you extend `b` to `{b, 2, 10}`, there are three contour lines. I just use `l1` to represent one of the contour line. I do not know whether there is a better way to extract the lowest line or the second lowest line.

Comment: @belisarius `ND` seems not a good solution for this problem.

Comment: @MarcoB any better method to extract the contour lines? I found the  contour lines in the figure is not ordered.

Comment: Related: "[Implementation of smoothing splines function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33206/280)."

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Yes, spline is one of the best choices for this kind of problem. I am still waiting for other thoughts on this problem, after that I will try to summarize possible methods mentioned in the answers.

Comment: The way to plot the derivative $dy/dx$ of `bs1` is something like `dbs[t_?NumericQ] := First@Ratios[bs'[t]]; xbs[t_?NumericQ] := First@bs[t]; ParametricPlot[{xbs[t], dbs[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]`, but it has noise similar to the `Interpolation` method.

Comment: @MichaelE2 up vote first. Do not quite understand, `FullForm` of `bs` is an `Unevaluated` object. I will search the site for more info.

Comment: The output of `bs[t]` is an xy pair *if* `t` is numeric.  The output of `bs'[t]` is the velocity vector, again *if* `t` is numeric, whose components are $dx/dt$ and $dy/dt$.  In other words, `bs[t]` is a parametric curve, but you can get at the components only numerically and not symbolically.  Another way to look at `bs` is that it is a data structure that *Mathematica* uses to compute a value when the input is numeric.

Answer (score 9):

This seems to be a perfect candidate for [`DifferentiatorFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferentiatorFilter.html):

```
t = TimeSeries[l1[[All, 2]], {l1[[All, 1]]}]

d = DifferentiatorFilter[t, .01];

ListLinePlot[d]
```

[image: smoothderiv]

I just had to adjust the cutoff frequency to weed out the fast oscillations. However, this filter scales the output differently for different cutoff frequencies.

**Unfortunately**, I believe the scaling of the derivative is a **bug.** If you go to the Help documentation, under "Scope," and evaluate the example for filtering a *time series*, the plot that *Mathematica* produces is *not* what the documentation shows as expected output before the evaluation. The expected output is the derivative, and it is scaled correctly. But after evaluation, you get a derivative that looks like a flat line in comparison to the original function. This is because the scaling is completely off. You have to fix it by hand.

Anyway, if it weren't for that bug, this *would be* the ideal solution, I think. **Update:** It has been confirmed by Wolfram Technical Support as a known bug. So if you're reading this in the future, you'll be able to use this answer...

Comment: A pretty good solution, but the y-axis seems not that right.

Comment: Yes, I think that's actually a bug. I see no reason whatsoever why the y-axis is scaled the way it is.

Comment: Thanks. Do you apply resampling on the list, I get an error like `DifferentiatorFilter currently only supports regularly sampled time \
series inputs. Use TimeSeriesResample or TemporalRegularity to make \
the input regularly sampled.`

Comment: Strange - I directly used the irregularly spaced data as you provide them in the question, and got no error message. I am using *Mathematica* version 10.1.0 on OS X. Would be interesting to find out what other versions do.

Comment: Interesting, just one subversion lower, I am using *Mathematica* version 10.0.

Comment: I have filed a bug report on this [CASE:3355498]. Let's see if I hear back from them.

Comment: I think I find the reason why the y value is not correct during I write the conclusion of this question. The cut-off frequency is too low, which cause the filter cut out most of the original data.

Comment: @Kattern With version 10.1 I get incorrect $y$-values with *any* value of the cut-off frequency: even `DifferentiatorFilter[t, 10^10]` produces incorrect $y$-scale.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I got confirmation from Wolfram that this is a known bug.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov For lowpass filter, it seems you can select an optimize cut off frequency.

Comment: @Jens It seems that starting from version 10.2 the behavior has changed: `DifferentiatorFilter[t, .01]` takes all the memory on my system with 8 Gb of RAM and computer becomes unusable. Constraining the memory usage via `MemoryConstrained[DifferentiatorFilter[t, .01], 5*^9]` gives `$Aborted`. `DifferentiatorFilter[t, 100]` produces the expected curve but with incorrect vertical scale. So we have additional bug while the old bug is still here.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I think you're right. I haven't tried 10.3 - maybe that will fix it.

Comment: @Jens I have checked v.10.3 - it is the same as with 10.2. :(

Comment: Even the [`LowpassFilter`-based solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85231/280) by @MichaelE2 kills my system with version 10.3. :(

Comment: Sems fixed / better in 11.0 - at least the documentation result is the same.

Comment: @flip I'm currently running a version 11 prerelease on Mac, and for me it *hangs* with the example in my answer or also with `LowpassFilter` in @Michael E2's answer... but you're right, the documentation example now works correctly. I haven't gotten the final version 11 yet.

Comment: @jens Well indeed, me too. Your example eventually crashes on MacOS with the final version 11. Ugh.

Answer (score 8):

You can use polynomial regression approach as suggested in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23872/280) answer:

```
lm = LinearModelFit[l1, x^Range[0, 6], x];
Plot[Evaluate@lm["Function"][x], {x, Min[l1[[;; , 1]]], 
  Max[l1[[;; , 1]]]}, PlotStyle -> Red, Prolog -> {Gray, Point[l1]}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Comparison of the model with original data"]
ListPlot[lm["FitResiduals"], PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "Differences between the original data and the model"]
Plot[Evaluate[lm["Function"]'[x]], {x, Min[l1[[;; , 1]]], 
  Max[l1[[;; , 1]]]}, PlotLabel -> "First derivative of the model"]
```

> [image: plot1]
>
> [image: plot2]
>
> [image: plot3]

---

And here is a spline fitting approach based on [Hug's idea](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72037/280):

```
Clear[model, y, x]
nOfControlPoints = 9;
controlPoints = 
  Subdivide[#1, #2, nOfControlPoints - 1] & @@ MinMax[data[[;; , 1]]];
model[y : {__Real}] := 
 Interpolation[Transpose[{controlPoints, y}], Method -> "Spline"]
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model[Array[y, nOfControlPoints]][x], 
   Array[y, nOfControlPoints], x];
Plot[Evaluate@nlm["Function"][x], {x, Min[data[[;; , 1]]], 
  Max[data[[;; , 1]]]}, PlotStyle -> Red, Prolog -> {Point[data]}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Comparison of the model with original data"]
ListPlot[nlm["FitResiduals"], PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLabel -> "Differences between the original data and the model"]
Plot[Evaluate@nlm["Function"]'[x], {x, Min[data[[;; , 1]]], 
   Max[data[[;; , 1]]]}, PlotLabel -> "First derivative of the model"]
```

> [image: plot1]
>   [image: plot2]
>   [image: plot3]

---

Another option is to use the [Quantile regression with B-splines](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/quantile-regression-with-b-splines/) package by Anton Antonov as described [here](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/04/19/find-fit-for-non-linear-data/) (or [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/224105)):

```
Needs["QuantileRegression`"]

qfunc = QuantileRegression[data, 30, {0.5}, 
     InterpolationOrder -> 2][[1]]; // Quiet

Plot[qfunc[x], {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red, Prolog -> Point[data], 
 PlotLabel -> "Comparison of the model with original data"]
ListPlot[data[[;; , 2]] - qfunc /@ data[[;; , 1]], PlotRange -> All, 
 Filling -> Axis, 
 PlotLabel -> "Differences between the original data and the model"]
Plot[qfunc'[x], {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}, 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotLabel -> "First derivative of the model"]
```

> [image: plot1]
>   [image: plot2]
>   [image: plot3]

Playing with the number of knots and interpolation order allows to get even better result. For example, with 20 equally-spaced knots and interpolation order 3:

```
qfunc = QuantileRegression[data, 20, {0.5}, 
     InterpolationOrder -> 3][[1]]; // Quiet
Plot[qfunc'[x], {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}, 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotLabel -> "First derivative of the model"]
```

> [image: plot4]

Comment: Thanks, but I do not think polynomial regression is a good choice for this job. They are not easy to control, and can be easily overfit. The devertaive calculated has obvious difference with the results posted above.

Comment: @kattern I updated the answer with another approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That latter one is definitely a good solution, I am disappoint by the result from `BSplineFunction` in *Mathematica*. This spline solution is absolutely the correct way to use spline in this question.

Comment: @kattern Added another option.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying `PiecewisePolynomialInterpolation` from [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56023/piecewise-polynomial-interpolation), surprisingly, not very hopeful.

Answer (score 7):

Signal-processing is not one of my strengths, but I think we used to use low-pass filters to remove such noise.  It seems to work here:

```
l2 = LowpassFilter[TimeSeries[l1], .05];
ifn = Interpolation[l2];

plot1 = Plot[Evaluate@Interpolation[l1]'[x], {x, 0, 0.5}, PlotStyle -> {Gray}];
plot2 = Plot[Evaluate@ifn'[x], {x, 0, 0.5}, PlotStyle -> {Red}];

GraphicsRow[{plot2, Show[plot1, plot2]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yes, `MovingAverage` is also another kind of low-pass filter. `MovingAverage` has phase delay in the result, I do not know whether low-pass filter in *Mathematica* is free of phase delay.

Comment: Your answer does what I would have expected my answer to do -  probably `DifferentiatorFilter` in my answer invokes `LowPassFilter` (+1).

Comment: @Jens I think so, looks like they have pretty close parameters.