# DerivativeFilter[] is scaling down the data by ~100 or so, not a true differentiation?

Tags: numerical-integration, bugs

I'm running the following function

```
 vzz = DerivativeFilter[z["Path"][[All, 2]], {1}];
```

But if I then integrate vzz the output z is about 100 smaller than the original z.

Why is this so? I thought DerivativeFilter would provide an alternative to a finite difference scheme but the magnitude of the output is just wrong.

Comment: If you read the docs for DerivativeFilter, you will see that it applies a spline interpolation and an optional Gaussian-like filter to the data, so it is not really much like a direct finite difference.

Comment: Try `DerivativeFilter[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {1}]`

Comment: Potentially related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85212/280

Comment: Confirmed as a bug in this answer: [(85214)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85214/121)

Comment: thanks guys! I guess we'll have to wait for an update.