# Interpolate contour line

Tags: plotting

I have a list of data points. From this list I generate a plot using ListCountourPlot. Mathematica interpolates multiple Countour lines.

I want to extract the points $(d,b)$ for a specific line which is the line $\omega_i = 0$ (red line).

How can I do that?

[image: figure]

Mathematica code:

```
j132 = Import["/home/mateus/Desktop/LaminarSeparationBubble/para_loop_20.dat"];

newStyle[x_] := x /. l_Line :> Sequence[Opacity[1], Thick, Red, l]

lista131 = 
  Table[{j132[[i, 2]], j132[[i, 1]], j132[[i, 9]]}, {i, 1, 
    Length[j132]}];

ListContourPlot[lista131, PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 30, 
  FrameLabel -> {"b", "d", "ωi"}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImageSize -> 400] /. Tooltip[x_, 0] :> Tooltip[newStyle[x], 0]
```

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code you used to produce this plot.

Comment: If your data is too large to post here, please put it on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/).

Comment: Edited Anton. Code posted.

Comment: We don't have your `para_loop_20.dat`; you've already been told where to post it.

Comment: I've exceed the maximum paste size, J.M.

Comment: @Mateus You exceeded the maximum on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)?

Comment: Yes @halirutan. I can't create a paste on pastebin because my archieve is vey large. I have a lot of points to make this graphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand, but it seems to me that you already have a method to isolate the `Line` element corresponding to that contour line. In fact, you do that in your `newStyle` function.

Try:

```
Cases[
  Normal@ListContourPlot[lista131, Contours -> {{0}}],
  Tooltip[x_, 0] :> Cases[x, l_Line :> l[[1]]], Infinity
]
```

Comment: My objective in fact is draw a tangent line (derivate = 0) at this curve (wi = 0). 
So my plan is get these coordinates (d,b) for wi = 0, interpolate and get the point when derivate is = 0.

Comment: @Mateus OK. Could you specify whether the method I proposed works to extract the (d, b) pairs at least? Also, if you need help with the rest of the problem, you should really include that in your original question.

Comment: @Mateus Strongly related: [(85212)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85212/280).

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyPopkov!

Comment: @MarcoB it works! Thanks a lot!