# Can I regroup terms into a sum?

Tags: summation

Is there a way to regroup terms into a sum? I mean, for example, if I have the sequence

$\quad \quad S_1 S_2 + S_2 S_3 + S_3 S_4 + S_4 S_5$

I would like to get the form

$\quad \quad {\rm Sum}[S_i\,S_{i+1},\ \{i,\,4\}]$.

I actually need this for a way longer and more complicated expression.

EDIT

Following the discussion in the comments, I think I should clarify the intent of the question: How do I construct a function that, given the input:

$\quad \quad S_1 S_2 + S_2 S_3 + S_3 S_4 + S_4 S_5$

gives the output

$\quad \quad {\rm Sum}[S_i\,S_{i+1},\ \{i,\,4\}]$

Comment: I recall that a similar question has been asked before, and I do not believe that any *general* answer was (or can be) given.  However if you give a sample of your expression I may be able to recommend a method.

Comment: Thanks, I think MovingMap pretty much solved it

Comment: Based on the answers received I don't think I understood the question.  However none of the answers actually return an expression involving `Sum` which is what I thought wanted.   Could you clarify your intent?  Would you give a short example of the specific input and the output that would like the hypothetical function to produce?

Comment: @user50473 Glad to help.  If you are accepting my answer may you click the check mark next to it.  It lets everyone know and answer has been accepted for the question.  Also, it would be my first accepted answer. :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Indeed now I run into a problem, Edmund's answer doesn't work for symbols (but  works great for numbers). So let's assume that the specific input and the desired output of my hypothetical function are exactly the ones stated in the question: the input is `S_1S_2+S_2S_3+S_3S_4+S_4S_5` and I want as output an expression involving `Sum` How would you construct such a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

```
exp = Subscript[S, 3] Subscript[S, 4] + 
  Subscript[S, 2] Subscript[S, 3] + Subscript[S, 4] Subscript[S, 5]
```

> $S_2 S_3+S_4 S_3+S_4 S_5$

This code `toSum` check for able form of `Sum` and if possible then it is applied `Defer`.

```
toSum[exp_] := Module[{l = List @@ exp, l2, s},
  l = l /. Subscript[S, a_] Subscript[S, b_] -> {a, b};
  s = l[[1, 1]];
  l2 = Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, s, s + Length[l] - 1}];
  If[l === l2, 
   Defer@Sum[
       Subscript[S,i] Subscript[S, i+1], {i, #1, #2}] & @@ {s, s+Length[l]-1}, 
    exp]
]
```

Have try this.

```
toSum[exp]
```

> $\sum _{i=2}^4 S_i S_{i+1}$

If it is not proper then return input expression.

```
exp2 = Subscript[S, 3] Subscript[S, 4] + 
  Subscript[S, 2] Subscript[S, 3] + Subscript[S, 4] Subscript[S, 6]
```

> $S_2 S_3+S_4 S_3+S_4 S_6$

```
toSum[exp2]
```

> $S_2 S_3+S_4 S_3+S_4 S_6$

**Original**

```
 data = {16, 13, 42, 26, 35, 39, 47, 49, 1, 9};
```

This is my try.

```
Most@data Rest@data
```

> `{208, 546, 1092, 910, 1365, 1833, 2303, 49, 9}`

```
Dot[Most@data, Rest@data]
```

> `8315`

Comment: Ok, looks like I didn't explain myself correctly: I would like to have a SYMBOLIC expression involving the function `Sum` as output. No numbers.

Comment: @user50473 I don't fully understand your question. Could you check? Is this right?

Comment: The update is good! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `MovingMap` in version 10.

```
data = RandomInteger[{1, 50}, 10]
(* {16, 13, 42, 26, 35, 39, 47, 49, 1, 9} *)
MovingMap[Times @@ # &, data, {2, Left}]
(* {208, 546, 1092, 910, 1365, 1833, 2303, 49, 9} *)
```

There you can see the items muliplied by the pairs.  Now just `Apply` `Plus` to get the total.

```
Plus @@ MovingMap[Times @@ # &, data, {2, Left}]
(* 8315 *)
```

Edmund

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Partition](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html):

```
data= {16, 13, 42, 26, 35, 39, 47, 49, 1, 9};
Times @@@ Partition[data, 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {208, 546, 1092, 910, 1365, 1833, 2303, 49, 9}
> ```

The summation of the list:

```
Plus@@(Times @@@ Partition[data, 2, 1])
```

> ```
>  8315
> ```

Comment: You can also use ``Tr @ Developer`PartitionMap[Times @@ # &, data, 2, 1]``

Comment: @RunnyKine,In V8,`DeveloperPartitionMap` is  not exist:-)

Comment: @RunnyKine, +1, I am always learnnig! BTW, I never knew Developer`PartitionMap

Comment: The way you typed it is not correct. You could be right since I don't have v8, but it's in v9 and 10

Comment: @RunnyKine, In V8,Developer`PartitionMap indeed exist!

Comment: Good to know :)

Comment: @ShutaoTang I didn't realise there was an offset to `Partition`.  That will come in handy.

Comment: @Edmund for additional partition flexibility see: [(7511)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7511/121)