# Generating a position lookup function for an arbitrary list of integers

Tags: function-construction

In my code, I generate a list of integers called `numlist`.  Here is an example `numlist`:

```
numlist = Sort[Table[RandomInteger[{1, 100}], {3}]]
```

which gives, for example, the output:

> {17, 74, 96}

I would like to write a function `generateFun` that, using `numlist` as input, generates the following function `myfun`:

```
myfun[int_Integer] := Which[
  int == 17, 1,
  int == 74, 2,
  int == 96, 3
  ]
```

In other words, `myfun` takes an integer and returns the position of that integer in `numlist`.  `numlist` is created at the beginning of the code and does not change during a given execution; however, a new execution will in general create a new list of integers `numlist`.  The length of `numlist` varies (it is not guaranteed to be 3), although this fact is not present in the minimal working example that I gave above.

I could bypass `generateFun` and simply use this function `myfun2`:

```
myfun2[int_Integer, numlist_] := First[First[Position[numlist, int]]]
```

which returns the position of `int_` in `numlist_`.  However, since I will need to call the function (`myfun` or `myfun2`) *many* times (~1,000,000 times), I think that calling `Position` every time may be quite expensive -- since `numlist`, once generated, does not change during the execution.

Do you have any advice on how I can generate the `Which` expression automatically from `numlist`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You really need a hash-table. Your method with `Which` statement won't scale to a large number of elements in a list, since `Which` does a linear look-up. Here are some possibilities.

#### `DownValues` and `SubValues`

Create one via `DownValues`, like @belisarius demonstrated in his answer.

#### `Dispatch`-ed replace rules

Another way (a little less stateful, since rules won't be attached to a symbol) is to use `Dispatch`-ed rules, like so:

```
lst = {2, 0, 11, 9, 20, 1, 16} 

rules = Dispatch@Thread[# -> Range[Length[#]]] &[lst]
```

Then, for example,

```
11 /. rules

(*  3  *)
```

#### `` System`Utilities`HashTable ``

Use `` System`Utilities`HashTable ``, like so:

```
h = System`Utilities`HashTable[];
MapThread[System`Utilities`HashTableAdd[h, ##] &, {lst, Range[Length[lst]]}];
```

where now you can extract the position for a given element as

```
System`Utilities`HashTableGet[h,11]

(* 3 *)
```

More details on the use of this hash table can be found in this [excellent answer by Oleksandr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/990/struct-equivalent-in-mathematica/1029#1029).

#### Using (sparse) arrays

Sometimes you may simply use arrays, or possibly sparse arrays, as a hash table. This is particularly useful for integer lists where integer values are not too large (although sparse arrays will handle also large values). I will demonstrate this by defining a new data type `storage`, like so:

```
Clear[makeStorage, storage];
makeStorage[lst_, $threshold_: 10^5] :=
  With[{len = Max[lst] - Min[lst] + 1},
    Module[{arr =  
       If[len < $threshold, 
              Table[0, {len}], 
              SparseArray[{0}, {len}, 0]
       ]}, 
      arr[[lst - Min[lst] + 1]] = Range[Length[lst]];
      storage[arr, Min[lst]]]];

storage /: getPosition[storage[arr_, min_], elem_] := arr[[elem - min + 1]];
```

Here is how you use it:

```
st = makeStorage[lst];

getPosition[st,11]

(* 3 *)
```

The advantage of this method is that when plain (non-sparse) arrays can be used,this will be the fastest one. The disadvantage is that using plain arrays is very memory-wasteful, so you trade memory for speed. You may wish to also define a bulk element extractor method

```
storage /: getPositions[storage[arr_, min_], elems_List] := 
    arr[[elems - min + 1]];
```

since this will be very efficient. You can see this approach put to practical use in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254923/how-to-select-rows-from-matrix-with-unique-entry-in-specific-column/7255008#7255008), where you can also see how much speed-up one can get by using it. I also put it (in a slightly different form) to use in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/efficient-conditional-mean-on-a-large-data-set/1671#1671), where it was inside `Compile`.

Answer (score 8):

I think the most straightforward way is:

```
MapIndexed[(f[#1] = #2[[1]]) &, numlist]

{#, f@#} & /@ numlist // TableForm
(*
7   1
81  2
96  3
*)
```

**Edit**

If you need to do this for an unknown number of lists and functions in your program, you could go:

```
defFun[g_Symbol, l_List]:= MapIndexed[(g[#1] = #2[[1]]) &, l]
```

Usage

```
ClearAll@h;
defFun[h, k = Table[Fibonacci@i, {i, 2, 10}]]
{#, h@#} & /@ k // TableForm
(*
1   1
2   2
3   3
5   4
8   5
13  6
21  7
34  8
55  9
*)
```

Comment: Just a warning. If your list contains duplicates, only the second one will get assigned. Example: if your list is `{1,2,1}`, then `f[1] == 3`

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays, one can just build an `Association[]`. Using Leonid's example:

```
assoc = Association[MapIndexed[# -> #2[[1]] &, {2, 0, 11, 9, 20, 1, 16}]];
```

or as Carl notes, you can use `PositionIndex[]` to build the required association:

```
assoc = First /@ PositionIndex[{2, 0, 11, 9, 20, 1, 16}];

assoc[11]
   3
```

If you need to get the values for two or more keys, use `Lookup[]`:

```
Lookup[assoc, {11, 9}]
   {3, 4}
```

Comment: You can use `PositionIndex` to create the association.

Comment: Thanks @Carl, I've edited.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use  [Nearest](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Nearest.html) or [Pick](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pick.html):

```
nf = Nearest[lst -> "Index"];
nf [ {11, 9, 3} , {1,0}]
```

> {{3}, {4}, {}}

To get both the index and the element:

```
nf2 = Nearest[lst -> {"Element", "Index"}];
nf2[ {11, 9, 3} , {1,0}]
```

> {{{11, 3}}, {{9, 4}}, {}}

```
Pick[Range @ Length @ lst, lst, #] & /@ {11,9,3}
```

> {{3}, {4}, {}}